# Why does the `map` method apparently not work on arrays created via `new Array(count)`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I've observed this in Firefox-3.5.7/Firebug-1.5.3 and Firefox-3.6.16/Firebug-1.6.2

When I fire up Firebug:

```js
var x = new Array(3)
console.log(x) 
// [undefined, undefined, undefined]

var y = [undefined, undefined, undefined]
console.log(y) 
// [undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log(x.constructor == y.constructor) // true

console.log( 
  x.map(function() { return 0; })
)
// [undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log(
  y.map(function() { return 0; })
)
// [0, 0, 0]
```

What's going on here?  Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how to use `new Array(3)`?

Comment: I don't get the same results you see from the array literal notation. I still get undefined instead of 0. I only get the 0 result if I set something like `var y = x.map(function(){return 0; });`, and I get this for both the new Array() method and the array literal. I tested in Firefox 4 and Chrome.

Comment: also busted in Chrome, this might be defined in the language, although it makes no sense so I really hope it isnt

Comment: when  you use new Array(4) the resul tis not array with 4 "undefined" you got diffrent result - you got "(4) [empty × 4]"

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It appears that the first example

```
x = new Array(3);
```

Creates an array with a length of 3 but without any elements, so the indices [0], [1] and [2] is not created.

And the second creates an array with the 3 undefined objects, in this case the indices/properties them self are created but the objects they refer to are undefined.

```
y = [undefined, undefined, undefined]
// The following is not equivalent to the above, it's the same as new Array(3)
y = [,,,];
```

As map runs on the list of indices/properties, not on the set length, so if no indices/properties is created, it will not run.

Comment: From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (emphasis mine): "`map` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. **`callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values**; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values."  In this case, `x`'s values have not explicitly assigned values, whereas `y`'s were assigned, even if it was the value `undefined`.

Comment: So is it a JavaScript failing that it's impossible to check whether it's an undefined pointer, or a pointer to undefined? I mean `(new Array(1))[0] === [undefined][0]`.

Comment: Well, an array of undefined is different from an array of pointers to undefined objects. An array of undefines would be like an array of null values, [null, null, null] while an array of pointers to undefined would be like [343423, 343424, 343425] poining to null and null and null. The second solutions have real pointers pointing to memory addresses while the first do not point anywhere. If that is a failing of JS is probably a matter o discussion, but not here ;)

Comment: @TrevNorris, you can easily test that with `hasOwnProperty` unless `hasOwnProperty` itself has a bug: `(new Array(1)).hasOwnProperty(0) === false` and `[undefined].hasOwnProperty(0) === true`. In fact, you can do the exact same with `in`: `0 in [undefined] === true` and `0 in new Array(0) === false`.

Comment: Talking about "undefined pointers" in JavaScript confuses the issue. The term you're looking for is ["elisions"](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array-initializer). `x = new Array(3);` is equivalent to `x = [,,,];`, not `x = [undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: I never claimed that the two are equal, on the contrary, its that they are NOT equal I emphase, that in the first case the array has a size but no content and the mapping function cannot run but in the second there is objects even if they are undefined and map can run as long as you do not try to access the object. OP was confused by the fact that the two rendered the same output in firebug while not behaving the same in the map function.

Comment: I'm curious. Under the hood (in C++ land, etc.), what is the pointer pointing to if it is an "undefined pointer"? Does javascript allocate a special location in memory that represents "being undefined".

Comment: The terminology is still wrong in this answer. The reason that `map` doesn’t execute its callback is that `new Array(3)` doesn’t have an index property up to its `length`. The point about `hasOwnProperty` is relevant: `map` will execute for every entry in `Object.keys(array)` (or `.values` or `.entries` etc.). If that’s empty, `map` will execute 0 times. This has nothing to do with “pointers”. The reason `new Array(3)[0]` is `undefined` is because that’s what non-existent properties produce. Good thing modern debugging tools make this difference more evident. “undefined object” is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 195):

I had a task that I only knew the length of the array and needed to transform the items.
I wanted to do something like this:

```
let arr = new Array(10).map((val,idx) => idx);
```

To quickly create an array like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But it didn't work because:
(see [Jonathan Lonowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501720))

The solution could be to fill up the array items with any value (even with undefined) using [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Fill)

```
let arr = new Array(10).fill(undefined).map((val,idx) => idx);
```

```js
console.log(new Array(10).fill(undefined).map((val, idx) => idx));
```

**Update**

Another solution could be:

```
let arr = Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map((val, idx) => idx);
```

```js
console.log(Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map((val, idx) => idx));
```

Comment: worth noting you don't need to state `undefined` in the `.fill()` method, simplifying the code very slightly to `let arr = new Array(10).fill().map((val,idx) => idx);`

Comment: Similarly you can use `Array.from(Array(10))`

Comment: I would recommend @eden-landau 's answer, since it's a cleaner way of initializing an array

Comment: The answer is incorrect

Comment: Remember to use return when mapping to an object. :X

`Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(() => { return {}; });`

Comment: @TrevorKarjanis thanks for the hint but feels not relevant. Where do I need an object here?

Comment: @cstuncsik You don't. You're returning an number `idx`. My comment is just to help anyone that followed your answer but needs to map to objects.

Comment: @TrevorKarjanis we're going way off topic here, but the crux of your statement is just how returned object literals work in a arrow functions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=vi#returning_object_literals

Comment: @Phil D Yep! I've known that and still make the mistake every once in a while.

Answer (score 121):

With ES6, you can do `[...Array(10)].map((a, b) => a)` , quick and easy!

Comment: Pre-ES6 you can use `new Array(10).fill()`. Same result as `[...Array(10)]`

Comment: With large arrays the spread syntax creates issues so it's better to avoid

Comment: or `[...Array(10).keys()]`

Comment: I know how it works, but please add **some explanation**, for those who don't

Answer (score 36):

ES6 solution:

```
[...Array(10)]
```

Doesn't work on typescript (2.3), though

Comment: `Array(10).fill("").map( ...` is what worked for me with Typescript 2.9

Answer (score 34):

From the MDC page for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description):

> [...] `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned value; [...]

`[undefined]` actually applies the setter on the index(es) so that `map` will iterate, whereas `new Array(1)` just initializes the index(es) with a default value of `undefined` so `map` skips it.

I believe this is the same for all [iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods).

Answer (score 23):

The arrays are different. The difference is that `new Array(3)` creates an array with a length of three but no properties, while `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` creates an array with a length of three and three properties called "0", "1" and "2", each with a value of `undefined`. You can see the difference using the `in` operator:

```
"0" in new Array(3); // false
"0" in [undefined, undefined, undefined]; // true
```

This stems from the slightly confusing fact that if you try to get the value of a non-existent property of any native object in JavaScript, it returns `undefined` (rather than throwing an error, as happens when you try to refer to a non-existent variable), which is the same as what you get if the property has previously been explictly set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 23):

For reasons thoroughly explained in other answers, `Array(n).map` doesn't work. However, in ES2015 [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from) accepts a map function:

```js
let array1 = Array.from(Array(5), (_, i) => i + 1)
console.log('array1', JSON.stringify(array1)) // 1,2,3,4,5

let array2 = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 2)
console.log('array2', JSON.stringify(array2)) // 2,4,6,8,10
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer to me.

Answer (score 10):

In ECMAScript 6th edition specification.

`new Array(3)` only define property `length` and do not define index properties like `{length: 3}`. see https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-len Step 9.

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]` will define index properties and length property like `{0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, length: 3}`. see https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation `ElementList` Step 5.

methods `map`, `every`, `some`, `forEach`, `slice`, `reduce`, `reduceRight`, `filter` of Array will check the index property by `HasProperty` internal method, so `new Array(3).map(v => 1)` will not invoke the callback.

for more detail, see https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map

How to fix?

```
let a = new Array(3);
a.join('.').split('.').map(v => 1);

let a = new Array(3);
a.fill(1);

let a = new Array(3);
a.fill(undefined).map(v => 1);

let a = new Array(3);
[...a].map(v => 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to explain this is to look at the way that Chrome handles it.

```
>>> x = new Array(3)
[]
>>> x.length
3
```

So what is actually happening is that new Array() is returning an empty array that has a length of 3, but no values. Therefore, when you run `x.map` on a **technically** empty array, there is nothing to be set.

Firefox just 'fills in' those empty slots with `undefined` even though it has no values.

I don't think this is explicitly a bug, just a poor way of representing what is going on. I suppose Chrome's is "more correct" because it shows that there isn't actually anything in the array.

Answer (score 6):

Not a bug.  That's how the Array constructor is defined to work.

From MDC:

> When you specify a single numeric parameter with the Array constructor, you specify the initial length of the array. The following code creates an array of five elements:

```
var billingMethod = new Array(5);
```

> The behavior of the Array constructor depends on whether the single parameter is a number.

The `.map()` method only includes in the iteration elements of the array that have explicitly had values assigned. Even an explicit assignment of `undefined` will cause a value to be considered eligible for inclusion in the iteration. That seems odd, but it's essentially the difference between an explicit `undefined` property on an object and a missing property:

```
var x = { }, y = { z: undefined };
if (x.z === y.z) // true
```

The object `x` does not have a property called "z", and the object `y` does. However, in both cases it appears that the "value" of the property is `undefined`. In an array, the situation is similar: the value of `length` does implicitly perform a value assignment to all the elements from zero through `length - 1`. The `.map()` function therefore won't do anything (won't call the callback) when called on an array newly constructed with the Array constructor and a numeric argument.

Comment: It's defined to be broken? It's designed to produce an array of three elements that will always be `undefined` for ever?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except for the "forever" part. You can subsequently assign values to the elements.

Comment: That's why you should use `x = []` instead of `x = new Array()`

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this. It sure would be convenient to be able to use `Array(n).map`.

`Array(3)` yields roughly `{length: 3}`

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]` creates the numbered properties:
`{0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, length: 3}`.

The map() implementation only acts on defined properties.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in order to easily fill up an array with values, can't use [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) for browser support reasons and really don't want to do a for-loop, you can also do `x = new Array(3).join(".").split(".").map(...` which will give you an array of empty strings.

Quite ugly I have to say, but at least the problem and intention are quite clearly communicated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is why, this has to do with how JS was designed.

There are 2 main reasons I can think of to explain this behavior:

- Performance: Given `x = 10000` and `new Array(x)` it is wise for the constructor to avoid looping from 0 to 10000 to fill the array with `undefined` values.
- Implicitly "undefined": Give `a = [undefined, undefined]` and `b = new Array(2)`, `a[1]` and `b[1]` will both return `undefined`, but `a[8]` and `b[8]` will also return `undefined` even if they're out of range.

Ultimately, the notation `empty x 3` is a shortcut to avoid setting and displaying a long list of `undefined` values that are `undefined` anyway because they are not declared explicitly.

Note: Given array `a = [0]` and `a[9] = 9`, `console.log(a)` will return `(10) [0, empty x 8, 9]`, filling the gap automatically by returning the difference between the two values declared explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple utility method as a workaround:

**Simple mapFor**

```js
function mapFor(toExclusive, callback) {
    callback = callback || function(){};
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < toExclusive; i++) {
        arr.push(callback(i));
    }
    return arr;
};

var arr = mapFor(3, function(i){ return i; });
console.log(arr); // [0, 1, 2]
arr = mapFor(3);
console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

**Complete Example**

Here's a more complete example (with sanity checks) which also allows specifying an optional starting index:

```js
function mapFor() {
var from, toExclusive, callback;
if (arguments.length == 3) {
    from = arguments[0];
    toExclusive = arguments[1];
    callback = arguments[2];
} else if (arguments.length == 2) {
    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        from = 0;
        toExclusive = arguments[0];
        callback = arguments[1];
    } else {
        from = arguments[0];
        toExclusive = arguments[1];
    }
} else if (arguments.length == 1) {
    from = 0;
    toExclusive = arguments[0];
}

callback = callback || function () {};

var arr = [];
for (; from < toExclusive; from++) {
    arr.push(callback(from));
}
return arr;
}

var arr = mapFor(1, 3, function (i) { return i; });
console.log(arr); // [1, 2]
arr = mapFor(1, 3);
console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined]
arr = mapFor(3);
console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

**Counting Down**

Manipulating the index passed to the callback allows counting backwards:

```js
var count = 3;
var arr = arrayUtil.mapFor(count, function (i) {
    return count - 1 - i;
});
// arr = [2, 1, 0]
```