# Cross browser random string (Math.random()*1e32).toString(36)

Tags: javascript

I use `(Math.random()*1e32).toString(36)` as a simple random string generator. It is very simple and works well and fullfils my needs (a temporal random to be used for ids, etc)

In chrome, safari, firefox and ie `Math.random()*1e32` generates numbers like: `8.357963780872523e+31` :-)

- In chrome, safari and firefox such number is converted into a string `(8.357963780872523e+31).toString(36)` -> `221fr2y11ebk4cog84wok` which is exactly I want.
- However in ie11 the string result is `6.936gwtrpf69(e+20)`.

How can I get the same string `221fr2y11ebk4cog84wok`from `8.357963780872523e+31` in a cross browser manner?

BTW: I got the idea of this random string from this thread: [Random alpha-numeric string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

Comment: What does `.toFixed(20)` mean ?

Comment: Do you need fixed number of characters, always?

Comment: not really. I just want to reduce possibilities of conflict with other external random id generators (I don't know what algorithms are used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind that `Math.random()` returns a value between 0 and 1 (exclusive), and that numbers in JavaScript have 53 bits mantissa as per IEEE-754, a safe way to get a random integer would be

```
Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 54)
```

So a random alphanumeric string could be obtained from

```
(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 54)).toString(36)
```

Note that there is no guarantee about the number of characters, which could be anything between 1 and 11 depending on the order of magnitude of the random value.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. So you are saying that multiplying by `*1e32` wat too much?

Comment: @nacho4d 1e32 is actually 10³², way too large.

Answer (score 3):

As fas as I can see, you don't need to multiply the random number by such a large number. Try this:

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
```

Does that suffice? It's a slightly shorter string but it's consistent in all browsers (that I tested).

Comment: the random string should not contain `.` or `(` or maybe other characters because they will be used like: `$('#' + randomID)` or even more complicated `'#table tr[data-iid=' + randomID +']'` which could brake things

Comment: causes every generated string to start with `0.`

Comment: This could be an option `Math.random().toString(36).replace('.', '_')`

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)`