# How to change part of an iFrame’s URL to a random string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Consider this simple iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/iframe/?user=123&name=test"
  width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

What I want is to randomly change the part `test`.

For example change this

```
src="http://example.com/iframe/?user=123&name=test"
```

to something like this:

```
src="http://example.com/iframe/?user=123&name=yxcvb"
```

The string should contain random letters of the alphabet and have a length of up to 10 characters, e.g.:

```
src="http://example.com/iframe/?user=123&name=qwertzuiop"
```

Comment: What content is inside the iframe? Why not just rotate the entire iframe?

Comment: The iframe content is another website. Which is not mine. I could just rotate the entire iframe and like write one by one myself every possibilities but that just would be like crazy amount of work...I'm sure theres have to be a way...

Comment: Do you want to rotate a string like rot13 or give name all permutions up to 10 characters?

Comment: Ohh god i'm soo noob in this whole topic. I dont know what do you want to ask actually xD But i might understand. What i want is to just randomly create those names from the alphabet or even numbers upto like 10character. So it can be anything like a 3 character name like just "aaa" or a 5character one like "aouto" etc. Not sure if thats can be understand... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could work for you:
[Random alpha-numeric string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

Just generate a random string (between 1 and 10 characters), and then assign it to the name attribute of the iframe.

I've put together a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4agLwfe8/.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.facebook.com?user=123&name=test" width="200" height="200">
```

This solution assumes you aren't using JQuery, since you said you weren't sure how to do this anyway, so it's a simply JavaScript solution.

To start you have a simple iframe. I just used facebook as a quick example. I also added an ID to it.

Then I used the following JavaScript

```
function randomNumber(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;  
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}

var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var iframeSrc = iframe.src;
var newIframeSrc = iframe.src.substring(0,iframe.src.indexOf("name")) + "name=" + randomString(randomNumber(), chars);
iframe.src = newIframeSrc;
```

First there are 2 functions. The first generates a random number between 1 and 10, this will be the length of the characters for your "name" parameter in your query string. The second function generates this random string, passing in the random number than was generated, and the string of characters (from the initial solution I linkted to) you specified you could use.

From there, I am simply selecting the iframe by the ID I gave it and grabbed it's source. With the source, I am simply cutting out the "name" parameter and it's value with the substring, and then appending the new "name" parameter and it's new value back on. Finally I'm assigning the new source for the iframe back to the iframe. In hindsight I realized I could have avoided chopping off "name=" only to add it back on again, but I started looking at this at 6:30am before my brain was fully awake. :)

Comment: Yea that might work. But the thing is my knowledge about these things are like literally nothing... And i'm trying to get things together and make it work but its just doesnt want to. 
Like i dont even know where to put these codes etc... Like no joke . I had websites before. I worked with php etc. But never rly got into things like this . So i'm kinda like a beginner in this whole thing...

Comment: lol i just wanted to answer "simple, do with css a transform: rotateZ(45deg);"...

Comment: That's what I was prepared to answer with when I first read the title of this questions ;)

Comment: @Metaton did this answer your question?