# Dynamic id for HTML element which is getting created newly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am replacing a span inside a table > td with option box.
I want to assign some unique id with dynamic value while creating the option box. How to achieve this?

Unique id is already generated , I want to set this unique id in Html while creation.

```
<td id="tdTest">
    <span id="spanId" class="connectedSlot" style="color:rgb(27,99,173)">Enabled</span>
</td>

$("#"+spanId).replaceWith(function () {
        return "<select class='form-control' id=<<DYNAMIC ID>> style='width:200px;'><option value='0'>Enabled</option><option value='1'>Disabled</option></select>";
});
```

For example , I will get some value from and assign to a variable and later assign this variable to id.

```
var myId = "OptionId"+test;

select class='form-control' id=myId style='width:200px;'>
```

Thanks

Comment: try Math.random(); jQuery function

Comment: Like this `"<select class='form-control' id='" + unqiueID +"' style='width:200px;'>...`

Comment: @Cobote , thanks a lot . It worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable within a string like this:

```
var unqiueID = "myID123", ret = "";
ret = "<select class='form-control' id='" + unqiueID +"' style='width:200px;'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to ensure that a unique value is assigned is to keep track of all the available id's and assign an id which isn't there in our list.

`getUniqueId()` is a function that will always return a unique id.

```
function getUniqueId() {

    //get all the ids in this document
    var ids = new Array();
    $('[id]').each(function() { //Get elements that have an id=
      ids.push($(this).attr("id")); //add id to array
    });


    //give some random value to uniqueId
    //if this value is in ids array, then assign a different id and recheck the condition
    var uniqueId;
    while(true) {
        uniqueId = 'some-prefix-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        if($.inArray(uniqueId , ids) == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return uniqueId;
}
```

Comment: ..Unique id is already generated , I want to set this unique id in Html while creation.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

```
function randomString(length) {
    return Math.round((Math.pow(36, length + 1) - Math.random() * Math.pow(36, length))).toString(36).slice(1);
}
```

Look into these Questions for others: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Unique id is already generated , I want to set this unique id in Html while creation.

Comment: @JavaUser maybe set it inside the elements onload event handler

Answer (score 0):

It's been several years since this was posted, and the accepted solution didn't work for me.  Here is the syntax that did:

[id]="unqiueID"