# How to generate a random letter when clicking a button in js

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a button with js that shows a random letter when I click it.

Comment: Math.random(); function could help.

Comment: What would be valid letters to produce?

Comment: @DevDig all lowercase letters

Comment: math.random to get index from array with valid letters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random alpha-numeric string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

Comment: It needs to be for a game, when you get a random letter you have to awnser with that letter

Comment: `onclick="alert('t') // randomly chosen by a stranger on the internet"`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) method along with [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method.

```js
console.log(
  String.fromCharCode(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
document.getElementById("rndletter").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var result = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
});
```

```html
<button id="rndletter">Generate random letter</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

- [`Math.random()` with min/max range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Using_Math.random())
- [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Answer (score 0):

Try This One :

**HTML File**

```
<form name="randform">
<input type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
</form>
```

**Javascript File**

```
<script>
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
</script>
```