# Generate short unique ID of 6 to 9 characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a unique id which I can assign to a user
it needs to be between 6 and 9 characters 
it can be alphanumeric 
I have seen this answer
[Random alpha-numeric string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

but it generates long ID, I want the ID to be between 6 and 9 characters

How can achieve this in javascript?

Comment: How do you measure "memorable"?

Comment: Well "memorable" is not only subjective but depends entirely on who has to remember it.

Comment: short between 6 and 9 characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random alpha-numeric string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
//Generating random
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
//Generating unique id
function id(n){
  var char = "";
  for(let i = 0;i<n;i+=1){
    char += String.fromCharCode(getRandomInt(32, 100));//alphanumeric chars
  }
  return char;
}
//test
for(let i=0;i<10;i+=1){
  var uniqueId = id(getRandomInt(6,9));//between 6 and 9 characters
  //result
  console.log(uniqueId, uniqueId.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you **could** do is to define an array of all allowed characters. Afterwards you loop over it as often your *ID* needs to be long. (Already posted by @Thomas Juranek)

Main issue here: how can be confirmed that it's unique? What is memorable? Do you have a storage were all used *ID*s are in (database, file, etc.)?

Another approach would be much more complicated: Combine parts of (fe. your MAC address) and a current timestamp. You can hash it to disguise the reference of this data.

But it mainly depends on your use case. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript?rq=1) one gives you also a spin