# How to generate string value for _id field in mongodb collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, meteor, mongoid

I want to generate id of the newly created object as string instead of BSON::ObjectId('59afe79b92caf8948b000005').

I am using mongoid of version mongoid (4.0.2) .

Is there anything like idGeneration of this page https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html .

I want to create id as random string(SWpabpucouNBRJZoh) so that it will work with our meteor application.

Any suggestion will helpful for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you generate it at your end and assign an `_id` field in insert query, mongo shall accept your `_id`. But if you don't specify any field by the name `_id` then mongoDB very intelligently creates an `_id` field which is generated with some algorithm which can be used for sorting purpose in future.

here is the information for how Object ID is generated by mongoDB. [Click Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification)

You can self generate an _id which is around 17 character (depends how long you need it). But before inserting make sure it does not already exists. MongoDB indexes the Keys identified by field `_id`. You can [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript) to know more how to generate your desired key. Take hints and develop your own code.

Answer (score 0):

As Ankur Soni pointed out, inserting items in the MongoDB without the `_id` property will result in Mongo creating its own. If you want to create your own id's, you can use something like a GUID generator (as seen here: [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)) to do the trick:

```
function guid() {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}
```