# Random alphanumeric string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, alphanumeric

I have to generate random alphanumeric sting in JavaScript like A123B456 or B001A556 (upper case letter, three numbers from 0-9, upper case letter, three numbers from 0-9).
This code should be randomly generated and should be unique. 
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: please go ahead and add some code, you tried.

Comment: Go to search engine. Paste in title. [Get answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726909/random-alpha-numeric-string-in-javascript). Remember to have a look around first, something like this is probably already solved.