# arr.forEach not producing expected result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill an Array created using `Array(5)` with the index of each element:

```js
let arr = Array(5)

arr.forEach((item, index) => arr[index] = index)

console.log(arr)

// expected output:
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

// instead I get 
// [
//   undefined,
//   undefined,
//   undefined,
//   undefined,
//   undefined
// ]
```

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: So it's actually possible to have an Array with an iterable length but no indices? That does not make much sense to me.

Comment: that *only* happens when you do that. If you said `new Array(3, 5);` you'd get `[3, 5]`. Additionally, there's no need to construct arrays that way, you don't have to specify the length ahead of time the way you would in C. You could always just do `Array.apply(null, Array(5))` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill it with function [`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

That array is actually empty, so the `forEach` doesn't iterate.

#### [`new Array(arrayLength)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> `arrayLength`
>
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

```js
let arr = Array(5).fill();
arr.forEach((item, index) => { arr[index] = index })
console.log(arr);
```

> Why does my code work when I change the first line to `let arr = [...Array(5)]`?

```
let arr = Array(5); 
Array.from(arr) // equals to [...arr];
```

`.apply` "expands" the elided elements into proper arguments, and the results ends up being something like Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined) [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281565/foreach-on-a-new-array-isnt-doing-what-i-expect)

Comment: The iteration **does** take place, only `index` is obviously `undefined` in each iteration. Otherwise how do I get an Array containing 5 `undefined` values?
Why does my code work when I change the first line to `let arr = [...Array(5)]`?

Comment: If you put a `console.log(…)` into the forEach method you can see that the interation does not take place; the method is not called. Do you, in your original example, really get “five undefined values?” I get “five empty slots,” and that's not the same.

Comment: @connexo see the updated answer.

Comment: Uh, no, `[...arr]` does not equal to `Array.apply(null, arr)`. It's the same as `Array.from(arr)` though.

Comment: @Bergi you're right will use the `length` attribute. However, the apply function will return an array with the `n` elements.