# Array map skipping elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an array.  Here's a simplified snippet of where I'm having a problem:

```
//should return an array with 10 elements with values of 0
var arr = Array(10).map(function() {return 0;});

console.log(arr.length); //returns 10
console.log(arr); //empty array
```

I understand that using `Array(length)` returns an array with `length` elements that are set to `undefined`.  I suspect `.map()` is skipping over `undefined` elements, but am not 100% sure about it.

What can I do to get the intended results?  I know I can accomplish the same thing with a loop, but I would really like to use `.map()` if possible.

--Update--

Can anyone explain why this works?

```
var arr = Array(10).join().split(',').map(function() {return 0;});
```

-edit- Disregard the update.  I figured out why it works.

Comment: There are no members in that Array. The iterator methods perform a `if (i in this)` check on every iteration to make sure the member actually exists as an own or inherited property.

Comment: You can do `Array.apply(null, Array(10))` to force creation of members. The `.apply()` method doesn't care if the collection given has actual members or not.

Comment: @cookiemonster You should add that as the answer :) .

Comment: I left an answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460301/foreach-on-array-of-undefined-created-by-array-constructor), but received 2 down votes, so I'll let someone else handle it. *(I also put the same `.apply()` solution in a comment since that question was just about the "why" part.)*

Comment: And FYI, ECMAScript 6 is going to have an `Array.prototype.fill()` method, so you could do `Array(5).fill(0);` to handle a zero initialized Array. It works right now in FireFox.

Comment: Yes, `map` skips over undefined elements. Consider the case of `var arr = []; arr[1000000] = 1; arr.map(...);`--we certainly don't want an array of one million elements coming back. Same holds for the other `Array.prototype` methods such as `forEach`.

Comment: @torazaburo the problem lies in the fact that the constructor does not really assign values to `N` indices, once you use apply as stated above and below, you can use these methods and actually loop `N` times (reduce, reduceRight, filter, map, forEach, some, and  every, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.apply` may accepts an object that can have a property length and based on it, push  `undefined` length times in it.

For instance:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10});
```

Which explains why you can also use [cookie monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096782/cookie-monster)'s suggestion:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10));
```

Because `Array(10)` will create property length with a value of 10 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JavaScript, you'd solve this with [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) (for static values) or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) using its mapping callback (if the values vary).

Static values -- `fill`:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 10}).fill(0);
console.log(arr);
```

Varying values -- `Array.from`:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.random());
console.log(arr);
```