# What's the difference between `[undefined, undefined]` and `new Array(2)`?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why this:

```
[undefined, undefined].map(function(i) { console.log(i); })
```

produces the expected output (2 times `undefined`), but this:

```
(new Array(2)).map(function(i) { console.log(i); })
```

doesn't?

Comment: What is the difference between assigning undefined to a property, and not setting a property at all? This is the same difference as `Array(n)` does not assign property values. There are definitely duplicates, especially wrt. `Array.map` / `Array.forEach` behavior (tldr; they iterate only *assigned* elements).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460301/foreach-on-array-of-undefined-created-by-array-constructor?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/2864740 (specific answer) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar?lq=1