# Array literal and array constructor methods are returning different results

Tags: javascript, arrays

We all know the difference between array literals and array constructors is subtle but [can be important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar). There seems to be another difference that is not noted in the referenced link. Take the following:

```
var x = new Array(5); // [undefined x 5];
var newArr = x.map(function () {return 'newValue'});
console.log(newArr); // [undefined x 5];
```

vs

```
var y = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
var newArr = y.map(function () {return 'newValue'});
console.log(newArr); // ['newValue', 'newValue', 'newValue', 'newValue', 'newValue'];
```

I would expect `x` and `y` to both be array instances and return the same result from the `.map` method. Seemingly oddly though, the array `x` produces an array that is not mappable whilst the literal `y` is mappable.

Why does `x` and `y` return different results from the `.map` method?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Arrays created by the Array constructor by passing in a number, are not iterable with array methods, such arrays have a length, but no values, they are literally undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305179/whats-the-difference-between-undefined-undefined-and-new-array2

Comment: @adeneo—or literally not defined. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> *map* calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array **which have assigned values, including undefined**. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

Comment: So.. I'm assuming this is the 'indexes which have never been set' category?