# Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component that accepts a JSON data source and creates a sortable table.
Each of the dynamic data rows has a unique key assigned to it but I'm still getting an error of:

> Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.
>   Check the render method of TableComponent.

My `TableComponent` render method returns:

```
<table>
  <thead key="thead">
    <TableHeader columns={columnNames}/>
  </thead>
  <tbody key="tbody">
    { rows }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `TableHeader` component is a single row and also has a unique key assigned to it.

Each `row` in `rows` is built from a component with a unique key:

```
<TableRowItem key={item.id} data={item} columns={columnNames}/>
```

And the `TableRowItem` looks like this:

```
var TableRowItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var td = function() {
        return this.props.columns.map(function(c) {
          return <td key={this.props.data[c]}>{this.props.data[c]}</td>;
        }, this);
      }.bind(this);

    return (
      <tr>{ td(this.props.item) }</tr>
    )
  }
});
```

What is causing the unique key prop error?

Comment: Your rows in JS array should have unique `key` property. It'll help ReactJS to find references to the appropriate DOM nodes and update only content inside mark-up but not re-render the whole table/row.

Comment: Can you also share `rows` array or more preferably a jsfiddle? You dont need a `key` property on `thead` and `tbody` by the way.

Comment: I added the row component to the original question @nilgun.

Comment: Is it possible that some items do not have an id or have same id?

Answer (score 935, accepted):

You should add a key to each child **as well as each element inside children**.

This way React can handle the minimal DOM change.

In your code, each `<TableRowItem key={item.id} data={item} columns={columnNames}/>` is trying to render some children inside them without a key.

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/1khqfLgr/2/).

Try removing the `key={i}` from the `<b></b>` element inside the div's (and check the console).

In the sample, if we don't give a key to the `<b>` element and we want to update **only** the `object.city`, React needs to re-render the whole row vs just the  element.

Here is the code:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Nuri", age: 28, city: "HO" },
  { name: "Talib", age: 82, city: "HN" },
  { name: "Jenny", age: 41, city: "IT" },
];

const ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    const infoData = this.props.info;
    return (
      <div>
        {infoData.map((object, i) => {
          return (
            <div className={"row"} key={i}>
              {[
                object.name,
                // remove the key
                <b className="fosfo" key={i}>
                  {" "}
                  {object.city}{" "}
                </b>,
                object.age,
              ]}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  },
});

React.render(<ExampleComponent info={data} />, document.body);
```

---

### **[The answer posted by @Chris at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/2325522) goes into much more detail than this answer.**

React documentation on the importance of keys in reconciliation: [Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

Comment: I added the component you're talking about to the original question.

Comment: Should I be adding a `key` to the `<tr>` element?

Comment: added extra info again nif it helps.

Comment: That doesn't fix it either. I added a key to the `<tr>` elements in `TableRowItem` and still get the error. 

I feel the error message would be different if the issue was within `TableRowItem` too. I originally did have the same error, but it referenced  the `TableRowItem` component. I fixed that by adding the `key` as a property of the component. The error is now referring to the `TableComponent`.

Comment: im tryng a fiddle with your code, is {this.props.data[c]} plain text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70260/discussion-between-3boll-and-brett-dewoody).

Comment: I am running into the exact same error. Was this resolved after the chat? If so, can you please post an update to this question.

Comment: The answer works, Deke. Just make sure that `key` value for the prop is unique for each item and you're putting the `key` prop to the component which is closest to array boundaries. For example, in React Native, first I was trying to put `key` prop to `<Text>` component. However I had to put it to `<View>` component which is parent of `<Text>`. if Array == [ (View > Text), (View > Text)] you need to put it to View. Not Text.

Comment: Why is is so hard for React to generate unique keys itself?

Comment: @DavorLucic, here is a discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939

Comment: [This is pretty much the official word](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) on a note made in the issue chat linked to above: keys are about identity of a member of a set and auto-generation of keys for items emerging out of an arbitrary iterator probably has performance implications within the React library.

Comment: should this key be unique only in that array or should be unique in the whole App?

Comment: @farmcommand2 "The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique." as per : https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: Linked to Codepen does not compile/run.

Comment: Is there documentation explaining why not only the child nodes need a unique key, but also the _children_ of those child nodes? I couldn't find anything about that specifically in the docs.

Comment: This requires more emphasis: "Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array. For example, if you extract a ListItem component, you should keep the key on the <ListItem /> elements in the array rather than on the <li> element in the ListItem itself." -- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: Except that this example uses index as key which causes another React error: `Do not use Array index in keys`

Comment: to broad code example that it's difficult to see that you just need to add `key={i}` inside your mapping tag to fix the issue.

Comment: In general you should not use the array index as the key — it loses all benefit if you reorder the array — instead use a unique feature of the data inside the array.

Comment: This is a fundamental design error in React. it should not be up to the caller to generate such keys. If React needs a unique key to track the item in the DOM, fine...it should generate it. Apologies that this doesn't actually give a solution...it's getting uncomfortable living with React with so many elephants in the room.

Comment: This is definitely not always the case. But in some scenarios, React seems to use a `.map` call internally for some code that we did not write with a `.map`. And sometimes the warning can appear and other times it won't, it is very inconsistent. In those cases, this solution does fix the problem...

Answer (score 899):

**Be careful when iterating over arrays!!**

It is a common misconception that using the index of the element in the array is an acceptable way of suppressing the error you are probably familiar with:

```
Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.
```

However, in many cases it is not! This is **anti-pattern** that can in *some* situations lead to **unwanted behavior**.

## Understanding the `key` prop

React uses the `key` prop to understand the component-to-DOM Element relation, which is then used for the [reconciliation process](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html). It is therefore very important that the key *always* remains *unique*, otherwise there is a good chance React will mix up the elements and mutate the incorrect one. It is also important that these keys *remain static* throughout all re-renders in order to maintain best performance.

That being said, one does not *always* need to apply the above, provided it is *known* that the array is completely static. However, applying best practices is encouraged whenever possible.

A React developer said in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939):

> - key is not really about performance, it's more about identity (which in turn leads to better performance). randomly assigned and changing values are not identity
> - We can't realistically provide keys [automatically] without knowing how your data is modeled. I would suggest maybe using some sort of hashing function if you don't have ids
> - We already have internal keys when we use arrays, but they are the index in the array. When you insert a new element, those keys are wrong.

In short, a `key` should be:

- **Unique** - A key cannot be identical to that of a [sibling component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings).
- **Static** - A key should not ever change between renders.

## Using the `key` prop

As per the explanation above, carefully study the following samples and try to implement, when possible, the recommended approach.

---

#### Bad (Potentially)

```
<tbody>
    {rows.map((row, i) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

This is arguably the most common mistake seen when iterating over an array in React. This approach isn't technically *"wrong"*, it's just... *"dangerous"* if you don't know what you are doing. If you are iterating through a static array then this is a perfectly valid approach (e.g. an array of links in your navigation menu). However, if you are adding, removing, reordering or filtering items, then you need to be careful. Take a look at this [detailed explanation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) in the official documentation.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: ["Item 1"]
    }
  }
  
  click = () => {
    this.setState({
      arr: ['Item ' + (this.state.arr.length+1)].concat(this.state.arr),
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.click}>Add</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.arr.map(
            (item, i) => <Item key={i} text={"Item " + i}>{item + " "}</Item>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Item = (props) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <label>{props.children}</label>
      <input value={props.text} />
    </li>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In this snippet we are using a non-static array and we are not restricting ourselves to using it as a stack. This is an unsafe approach (you'll see why). Note how as we add items to the beginning of the array (basically unshift), the value for each `<input>` remains in place. Why? Because the `key` doesn't uniquely identify each item.

In other words, at first `Item 1` has `key={0}`. When we add the second item, the top item becomes `Item 2`, followed by `Item 1` as the second item. However, now `Item 1` has `key={1}` and not `key={0}` anymore. Instead, `Item 2` now has `key={0}`!!

As such, React thinks the `<input>` elements have not changed, because the `Item` with key `0` is always at the top!

**So why is this approach only *sometimes* bad?**

This approach is only risky if the array is somehow filtered, rearranged, or items are added/removed. If it is always static, then it's perfectly safe to use. For example, a navigation menu like `["Home", "Products", "Contact us"]` can safely be iterated through with this method because you'll probably never add new links or rearrange them.

In short, here's when you can **safely** use the index as `key`:

- The array is static and will never change.
- The array is never filtered (display a subset of the array).
- The array is never reordered.
- The array is used as a stack or LIFO (last in, first out). In other words, adding can only be done at the end of the array (i.e push), and only the last item can ever be removed (i.e pop).

Had we instead, in the snippet above, **pushed** the added item to the end of the array, the order for each existing item would always be correct.

---

#### Very bad

```
<tbody>
    {rows.map((row) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={Math.random()} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

While this approach will probably guarantee uniqueness of the keys, it will *always* force react to re-render each item in the list, even when this is not required. This a very bad solution as it greatly impacts performance. Not to mention that one cannot exclude the possibility of a key collision in the event that `Math.random()` produces the same number twice.

> Unstable keys (like those produced by `Math.random()`) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.

---

#### Very good

```
<tbody>
    {rows.map((row) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={row.uniqueId} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

This is arguably the [best approach](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) because it uses a property that is unique for each item in the dataset. For example, if `rows` contains data fetched from a database, one could use the table's Primary Key (*which typically is an auto-incrementing number*).

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys

---

#### Good

```
componentWillMount() {
  let rows = this.props.rows.map(item => { 
    return {uid: SomeLibrary.generateUniqueID(), value: item};
  });
}

...

<tbody>
    {rows.map((row) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={row.uid} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

This is also a good approach. If your dataset does not contain any data that guarantees uniqueness (*e.g. an array of arbitrary numbers*), there is a chance of a key collision. In such cases, it is best to manually generate a unique identifier for each item in the dataset before iterating over it. Preferably when mounting the component or when the dataset is received (*e.g. from `props` or from an async API call*), in order to do this only *once*, and not each time the component re-renders. There are already a handful of libraries out there that can provide you such keys. Here is one example: [react-key-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index).

Comment: In the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), they use `toString()` to convert to string instead of leaving as number. Is this important to remember?

Comment: @skube, no, you can use integers as `key` as well. Not sure why they are converting it.

Comment: I guess you _can_ use integers but _should_ you? As per their docs they state "...best way to pick a key is to use a **string** that uniquely identifies..." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @skube, yes that is perfectly acceptable. As stated in the examples above, you can use the item's index of the iterated array (and that's an integer). Even the docs state: *"As a last resort, you can pass item's index in the array as a key"*. What happens though is that the `key` always ends up being a String anyway.

Comment: should this key be unique only in that array or should be unique in the whole App?

Comment: @farmcommand2, keys are applied to React Components, and need to be unique among **siblings**. This is stated above. In other words, unique in the array

Comment: All numbers can be silently coerced into a string by the library itself, and there's *generally* (barring very large or very small numbers) a 1:1 ratio between a value's numeric representation and it's string representation (i.e. 5's string representation will always be "5" and vice versa).

Comment: @skube The reason is likely there's some type coercion "under the hood" so they just made a blanket statement to stick with strings. That's just an educated guess.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate the importance of "it is best to manually generate a unique identifier for each item in the dataset before iterating over it. Preferably when mounting the component or when the dataset is received"
I keep seeing people write `key={uuid()}` inside of the render function.  This is **not correct** and causes the element to rerender when it shouldn't.  As @Chris said, it should be done **only once**.

Comment: @Jordan It might seem incorrect, but doing `uuid()` in most "uuid" libraries will generate a key that remains static throughout re-renders (through memoization or other means), thus making that approach perfectly valid. As mentioned in my answer, the react-key-index library is an example of such behavior.

Comment: @Chris I've seen it cause a rerender every time in the codebase I'm working in.  I also ran a test in codepen with the cuid package and it had the same undesirable behavior.  My intent is to warn others from thinking that they can just use a uuid to solve the problem.  Can you explain how most uuid libraries solve this problem?
react-key-index requires additional data to be passed in so that it can memoize.  I don't understand how a generic uuid lib could accomplish the same thing by calling it with no arguments.

Comment: @Jordan I might've been wrong about how one implements react-key-index (probably confused it for another library), however I do know that there are libs out there that work as I described above. Can't recall the lib names though.

Comment: @Chris I would be fascinated to know how they work if they don't have access to any additional data.

Comment: This requires more emphasis: "Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array. For example, if you extract a ListItem component, you should keep the key on the <ListItem /> elements in the array rather than on the <li> element in the ListItem itself." -- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: Also worth pointing out is that the issue demonstrated in the code snippet (array values not updating to the correct location because of improper keys) will only manifest itself if you do not store these values directly in your array. However, even if you do, if you have changing keys, you will still lose in performance as React will have to update all the array items' values as their keys have changed.

Answer (score 66):

This may or not help someone, but it might be a quick reference. This is also similar to all the answers presented above.

I have a lot of locations that generate list using the structure below:

```
return (
    {myList.map(item => (
       <>
          <div class="some class"> 
             {item.someProperty} 
              ....
          </div>
       </>
     )}
 )
```

After a little trial and error (and some frustrations), adding a key property to the outermost block resolved it. Also, note that the `<>` tag is now replaced with the `<div>` tag now.

```
return (
  
    {myList.map((item, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
          <div class="some class"> 
             {item.someProperty} 
              ....
          </div>
       </div>
     )}
 )
```

Of course, I've been naively using the iterating index (index) to populate the key value in the above example. Ideally, you'd use something which is unique to the list item.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you! I didn't even realize I had to put it in the outermost layer

Comment: I was doing similar groupings, but with table rows. You cannot wrap a table row in a div. Instead, wrap it in a react Fragment with a key, as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875412/750914

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. I was using <></> inside map() Removing that helped me.

Comment: <> is a short syntax for <React.Fragment>. 

So if you want to add a key you can do like this:

<React.Fragment key={item.id}>

Comment: I had the same issue using Material-UI where I was using a List (and elsewhere a Menu) and placing the child items of those components inside a Tooltip. 

Giving the Tooltip the "key" instead of the ListItem/MenuItem itself got rid of the warning.

Comment: This was my issue too. I missed the Fragment.

Comment: Ahh, well done, this was my issue as well. Thank you!

Comment: you saved me thank youuuuuu ive been trying so long to solve my issue

Comment: Thank you, removing the empty tag (added for convenience) solved it.

Answer (score 15):

Check: key = undef !!!

You got also the warn message:

```
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

if your code is complete right, but if on

```
<ObjectRow key={someValue} />
```

someValue is undefined!!! Please check this first. You can save hours.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the React docs that explain well using the Key property, the key should be defined at the parent component it should not be used inside the child component.[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31777672)

Answer (score 8):

You should use a unique value for each children key of `tbody` where

- the value cannot not be **identical (same)** to its sibling
- should not change between renders

For example, the key value can be **database id** or **[UUID (Universal Unique Identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)**.

Here the keys are handling manually:

```
<tbody>
  {rows.map((row) => <ObjectRow key={row.uuid} />)}
</tbody>
```

You can also let React handle the keys using [React.Children.toArray](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray)

```
<tbody>
  {React.Children.toArray(rows.map((row) => <ObjectRow />))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add the **unique key** to the your Components

```
data.map((marker)=>{
    return(
        <YourComponents 
            key={data.id}     // <----- unique key
        />
    );
})
```

Comment: The key `data.id` can't possibly be unique among the `YourComponents`.

Answer (score 5):

Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

This is a warning as for array items which we are going to iterate over will need a unique resemblance.

React handles iterating component rendering as arrays.

Better way to resolve this is provide index on the array items you are going to iterate over.for example:

```
class UsersState extends Component
    {
        state = {
            users: [
                {name:"shashank", age:20},
                {name:"vardan", age:30},
                {name:"somya", age:40}
            ]
        }
    render()
        {
            return(
                    <div>
                        {
                            this.state.users.map((user, index)=>{
                                return <UserState key={index} age={user.age}>{user.name}</UserState>
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
        }
```

index is React built-in props.

Comment: This approach is potentially dangerous if the items are rearranged somehow. But if they remain static then this is fine.

Comment: @chris I completely agree with you because in this case index may be duplicated. Better to use dynamic values for key.

Comment: @chris I also agree with your comment. We should use dynamic values rather then index because there may be duplicates. To make it simple I did this. Btw thanks for your contribution (upvoted)

Answer (score 5):

When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort:

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
// Only do this if items have no stable IDs
   <li key={index}>
      {todo.text}
   </li>
);
```

Please refer to [List and Keys - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 4):

In ReactJS if you are rendering an array of elements you should have a unique key for each those elements. Normally those kinda situations are creating a list.

Example:

```
function List() {
  const numbers = [0,1,2,3];
 
  return (
    <ul>{numbers.map((n) => <li> {n} </li>)}</ul>
  );
}

 ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the above example, it creates a dynamic list using `li` tag, so since `li` tag does not have a unique key it shows an error.

After fixed:

```
function List() {
  const numbers = [0,1,2,3];
 
  return (
    <ul>{numbers.map((n) => <li key={n}> {n} </li>)}</ul>
  );
}

 ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Alternative solution when use map when you don't have a unique key (this is not recommended by react [eslint](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md) ):

```
function List() {
  const numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,4];
 
  return (
    <ul>{numbers.map((n,i) => <li key={i}> {n} </li>)}</ul>
  );
}

 ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/wvWdGwG

Answer (score 3):

Best solution of define unique key in react:
inside the map you initialized the name post then key define by key={post.id} or in my code you see i define the name item then i define key by key={item.id}:

```js
<div className="container">
                {posts.map(item =>(

                    <div className="card border-primary mb-3" key={item.id}>
                        <div className="card-header">{item.name}</div>
                    <div className="card-body" >
                <h4 className="card-title">{item.username}</h4>
                <p className="card-text">{item.email}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

Comment: was looking for this same answer even I had a component like this and was frustated

Answer (score 3):

If we have array object data . then we map to show the data . and pass the unique id (key = {product.id} ) because browser can select the unique data.

```
example : [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "walton glass door",
        "suplier": "walton group",
        "price": "50000",
        "quantity": "25",
        "description":"Walton Refrigerator is the Best Refrigerator brand in bv 
         Bangladesh "
    },
    {
        
        "id": "2",
        "name": "walton glass door",
        "suplier": "walton group",
        "price": "40000",
        "quantity": "5",
        "description":"Walton Refrigerator is the Best Refrigerator brand in 
         Bangladesh "
    },
}
```

now we are mapping the data and pass the unique id:

```
{
    products.map(product => <product product={product} key={product.id} 
    </product>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this error message because of `<></>` being returned for some items in the array when instead `null` needs to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I had a unique key, just had to pass it as a prop like this:

```
<CompName key={msg._id} message={msg} />
```

This page was helpful:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 2):

In my case, set id to tag

```
<tbody key={i}>
```

The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

A visual explanation.

1. The incorrect way key=index (of an array)

[image]

As you can see, label 3, label 2, and label 1 **ALL** got re-rendered (flashing in the Elements panel).

2. The correct way key=uniqueId
   [image]

**Only** the top new element flashes (gets re-rendered).

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning, But ***addressing this will make Reacts rendering much FASTER***,

This is because `React` needs to uniquely identify each items in the list. Lets say if the state of an element of that list changes in Reacts `Virtual DOM` then React needs to figure out which element got changed and where in the DOM it needs to change so that browser DOM will be in sync with the Reacts Virtual DOM.

As a solution just introduce a `key` attribute to each `li` tag. This `key` should be a unique value to each element.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Rendering will **not** be faster if you add the `key` prop. If you don't provide one, React will assign one automatically (the current index of the iteration).

Comment: @Chris in that case why it raise a warning ?

Comment: because by not providing a key, React doesn't know how your data is modelled. This can lead to undesired results if the array is modified.

Comment: @Chris in that case of array modification, will React correct the indices according to that if we did not provide keys. Anyway I thought removing extra overhead from React will make some impact on the rendering process.

Comment: again, React will basically do `key={i}`. So it depends on the data your array contains. For example, if you have the list `["Volvo", "Tesla"]`, then obviously the Volvo is **identified** by the key `0` and the Tesla with `1` - because that is the order they will appear in the loop. Now if you reorder the array the keys are swapped. For React, since "object" `0` is still at the top, it will rather interpret this change as a "rename", rather than a reorder. The correct keys here would need to be, in order, `1` then `0`. You don't always reorder mid runtime, but when you do, it's a risk.

Answer (score 1):

```
var TableRowItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var td = function() {
        return this.props.columns.map(function(c, i) {
          return <td key={i}>{this.props.data[c]}</td>;
        }, this);
      }.bind(this);

    return (
      <tr>{ td(this.props.item) }</tr>
    )
  }
});
```

This will sove the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are getting error like :

> index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Home`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

Then Use inside map function like:

  {classes.map((user, index) => (
              <Card  **key={user.id}**></Card>
  ))}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example,I have used a react condition with `&&` first then map, in the  I have added the `key` the user id to be sure that it's unique

```
 <tbody>
                                    {users &&
                                    users.map((user) => {
                                        return <tr key={user._id}>
                                            <td>{user.username}</td>
                                            <td><input
                                                name="isGoing"
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                checked={user.isEnabled}
                                                onChange={handleInputChangeNew}/></td>
                                            <td>{user.role.roleTitle} - {user.role.department.departmentName}</td>
                                            {/*<td className="text-right">
                                                    <Button>
                                                        ACTION
                                                    </Button>
                                                </td>*/}
                                        </tr>
                                    })
                                    }


                                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

your key should be unique.like an unique id.And your code should be like this

```
<div>
 {products.map(product => (
   <Product key={product.id}>
    </Product>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), each row/item should have a **unique** key.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Personally, I prefer using the [crypto interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) to generate a random UUID: 
(`crypto` is built-in in vanilla-js)

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={crypto.randomUUID()}>item {number}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: With every render cycle, you are calling the randomizer to assign a new key to each `li`, forcing them to re-render. This is highly inefficient. Rather, you should ensure that the assigned ID does not change if the list item does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to deal with deletion and addition of children with no unique keys.

So I ended up using UUID as keys and wrapped them in useMemo based on the number of elements.

```
  const uniqueKeys = useMemo(() =>
    data.map(_ => uuidv4()),
    [data.length]
  );

  // in render
  {data.map((item, index) => (
     <Tr key={uniqueKeys[index]}>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was puzzled by this until I looked *very* carefully at my code - so this is what I had - spot the bug:

```
{
  items.map(
    (item) => {
      
      return (<>
         <IonItem key={item.id}>
             <p>{ item.name }</p>
         </IonItem>
      </>);
    }
  )
}
```

So, I had a `key` attribute on my "item" component (`<IonItem>`) - still React complained about a lack of a unique key on my list items ...

The bug of course was that I erroneously wrapped the whole thing in `<>` and `</>` which do NOT have a `key` property ... once I removed this (unnecessary) `<>...</>` wrapper, the error disappeared.

Maybe this is obvious, but it's VERY easy to overlook ... it had me puzzled for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't go with the detail explanation but the key to this answer is "key"
just put the key attribute in your tag and ensure that every-time you iterate you give unique value to it

#ensure that the key's value is not clashing with others

Example

```
<div>
        {conversation.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id  } id={item.id}>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

where the conversation is an array of something like below :

```
  const conversation = [{id:"unique"+0,label:"OPEN"},{id:"unique"+1,label:"RESOLVED"},{id:"unique"+2,label:"ARCHIVED"},
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when working with tables (or in similar examples), creating a unique key should be passed to the child component from the parent component for the sake of REUSABILITY.

Because if you are creating a table, that means you are passing data from the parent.  If you assign `key={row.name}` maybe currently data has `name` property but if you want to use this table component somewhere else you assume that in each row of data that you have passed, you have `name` property.

Since the engineer will be preparing the data in the parent component, the engineer should create a key function based on the data.

```
const keyFunc = (student) => {
    return student.id;
  };
```

In this case, the engineer knows what data it is sending, it knows that each row has an id property that is unique. Maybe in the different data set, the data set is stock prices and it does not have "id" property but "symbol"

```
 const keyFunc = (stock) => {
        return stock.symbol;
      };
```

this `keyFunc` should be passed to the child component as a prop to guarantee reusability and uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many times people rendering fragments `<></>` and it generates this issue. Try to change the fragments to `null` or a component with a unique `key`

Answer (score 0):

For React official docs

The `key` should be inside `<li key={person}>{person}</li>`

```js
const people = [
  'Creola Katherine Johnson: mathematician',
  'Mario José Molina-Pasquel Henríquez: chemist',
  'Mohammad Abdus Salam: physicist',
  'Percy Lavon Julian: chemist',
  'Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar: astrophysicist'
];

export default function List() {
  const listItems = people.map(person =>
    <li key={person}>{person}</li>
  );
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code (App.jsx), just use it to your file

```
const ListItem = (props) => (
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p> {props.title} </p>
  </li>
);

const productList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Shirt',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Pant',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Cap',
    checked: false
  },
]

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {productList.map((item) => (
            <ListItem key={item.id} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score -1):

> If you are struggling with this error **Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

> Solve by declaring index value to the key attribute inside the rendering element.

> App.js component

```
import Map1 from './Map1';

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
     
     <Map1 numb={arr} />     

    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

> Map.js component

```
const Map1 = (props) => {

    let itemTwo = props.numb;
    let itemlist = itemTwo.map((item,index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)

    return (
        <>        
        <ul>
            <li style={liStyle}>{itemlist}</li>
        </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export default Map1
```

Answer (score -2):

The "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." warning happens in React when you create a list of elements without the special key attribute. Keys must be assigned to each element in a loop to give stable identity to elements in React.

We can set the id property of the object as a unique key.

```
export default function App() {
      const posts = [
{ id: 1, title: "First "},
{ id: 2, title: "Second" },
{ id: 3, title: "Third" }
 ];
 return (
<div>
    <ul>
        {posts.map(value => 
            <li key={value.id}>{value.title}</li>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
 );}


//simple way

//if u using ant design remove the empty fragment...

//worng ans---> change to following crt ans

export default function App() {
      const posts = [
{ id: 1, title: "First "},
{ id: 2, title: "Second" },
{ id: 3, title: "Third" }
 ];
 {fields.map((field,index)=>{
return(
  <> //empty fragment
   <Row key={index}>
    <Col span={6}>hello</Col>
   </Row>
  </>
)
})}

 //correct ans
//remove the empty fragments after solve this key.prop warning problem
export default function App() {
      const posts = [
{ id: 1, title: "First "},
{ id: 2, title: "Second" },
{ id: 3, title: "Third" }
 ];
 {fields.map((field,index)=>{
return(
  <> //empty fragment
   <Row key={index}>
    <Col span={6}>hello</Col>
   </Row>
  </>
)
})}
```

Comment: I may be incorrect but the `key` needs to be on the highest element that's iterated over, so if you're including the fragments they'd need to be changed to `<React.Fragment key={index}><React.Fragment />`. Sadly you can't include a key in an empty fragment. But I don't think they're necessary as there's only one parent element inside the `map`

Answer (score -4):

I faced a similar problem but not exact. Tried every possible solution and couldn't get rid of that error

> Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.

Then I tried opening it in a different local host. I don't know how, but it worked!

Comment: This is most likely an issue with **browser cache**. You can [hard-refresh](https://superuser.com/a/512833/863212) on the same local host to remove any stored cache.