# How to repeat an element n times using JSX and Lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am using React/JSX and Lodash in my app in order to accomplish what I want.

I need to repeat an element a certain amount of times depending on a condition. How should I do that?

Here is the element:

```
<span className="busterCards">♦</span>;
```

And I am assigning it like this:

```
let card;
if (data.hand === '8 or more cards') {
  card = <span className='busterCards'>♦</span>;
}
```

So in this case, I need to repeat the element `8` times. What should be the process using Lodash?

Comment: How about `new Array(8).join('<span className="busterCards">♦</span>');`?

Comment: The solution that @Vohuman suggested is a very clean way to get the job done. There is no comparable function defined within the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs).

Comment: @Vohuman it would generate a String, while OP wants to create DOM using JSX syntax.

Comment: @Vohuman it is weird but I am getting rendered the whole string

Comment: @pawel you are right, do you know how can I do it ?

Comment: linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/25646502/104380

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let card = [];
_.times(8, () => {
  card.push(<span className="busterCards">♦</span>);
});
```

You may want to add key to each `span` element so React won't complain about missing the key attribute:

```
let card = [];
_.times(8, (i) => {
  card.push(<span className="busterCards" key={i}>♦</span>);
});
```

For more info about `.times`, refer here: https://lodash.com/docs#times

Comment: I am trying to assign this to the `let card`, but it is not repeating the element

Comment: Or simply `const card = _(8).times(idx => <span key=${idx} className="busterCards">♦</span>);`

Comment: You can also simply return _.times(.....) to render the elements. Make sure you also use return (<Element></Element) inside too.

Answer (score 519):

The shortest way to do this **without any external libraries**:

```js
const n = 8; // Or something else

[...Array(n)].map((e, i) => <span className="busterCards" key={i}>♦</span>)
```

Comment: Awesome answer for non-lodash users! Worth pointing out that it does require ES6 features (though I think it's implied by using `let` in the question anyway).

Comment: For those using Typescript 2+, this will compile into `Array(3).slice().map(...)` which doesn't achieve the same result. See @Jian's answer below as a replacement.

Comment: Nice, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359938/104380) which elaborates more

Comment: Typescript recently added a tsconfig flag `"downlevelIteration": true` which _will_ compile this code correctly to ES5.

Comment: Why can't this just be `Array(n).map((e, i) => <span className="busterCards" key={i}>♦</span>)`

Comment: @KevinWang because your suggestion will create an **empty** array with a length of 8, rather than an array consisting of 8 undefined items. Iteration won't work on the former. Chuck it in the console to see the difference.

Comment: This is working as expected in Typescript version 4

Comment: This conflicts with `eslint-plugin-react` rule called [`react/no-array-index-key`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md), but I can't think of a better way...  Guess I'll just have to disable that rule.

Comment: @Garrett that rule's documentation explicitly says to not use the rule "If there is nothing unique about the items" - which is literally the case here. Therefore you shouldn't feel bad disabling the linter rule here.

Answer (score 65):

solution without lodash or ES6 spread syntax:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map((e, i) => (
  <span className="busterCards" key={i}>
    ♦
  </span>
));
```

Comment: This seems more clean, but with more iterations than around 126000 I'm getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" (at least in Chrome web desktop)

Comment: I came across a coworker using this code, and using Array.apply to loop a specific number of times was not intuitive to me at first glance. I'd personally consider other more intuitive solutions first if future devs will read your code.

Comment: I am sorry to hear about that. The solution aims to use as less dependencies as possible. I would suggest your coworker improving the readability by making it a reusable function with sensible name like `times`.

Answer (score 36):

**Implementing this without Lodash**

```
<section>
      {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => <span key={i}>Your text</span>)}
 </section>
```

**How does this work?**

`Array.from()` is used in two contexts:

1. Creating an array from an array-like data structure. For example, we can convert a map into an array using `Array.from()`

   `const map = new Map([ [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5] ])`

   `console.log(Array.from(map)) //gives an array - [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]`
2. Creating an array and filling out the values (This can be handy when we need to create an array containing more elements)

`Array.from()` accepts an object and a callback function.

`Array.from({ length: 7 }, (() => 10)) // gives [10,10,10,10,10,10,10]`

We can take advantage of the index (second parameter) inside the callback function to provide unique array elements

`Array.from({ length: 4 }, ((_, i) => i + 1)) // [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: `Array.from` is much more readable/understandable than `[...Array(n)]`

Answer (score 17):

I'm using this and works for me.

```
[...Array(10)].map((elementInArray, index) => ( 
    <div key={index}>
      Text in Loop
    </div>
))
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `_.times`: https://jsfiddle.net/v1baqwxv/

```
var Cards = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>cards {
          _.times( this.props.count, () => <span>♦</span> )
        }</div>;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Straight forward options ways to do that without any external libraries (2021):

```
// straight forward but without key index. Not so good for react but work fine with worning 
Array(X).fill(<span className="busterCards">♦</span>)
// with index
Array(X).fill().map((v,i)=> <span className="busterCards">♦</span>)
```

```
Array.from( Array(X), (v,i) => <span key={i} className="busterCards">♦</span> )
// same thing basically 
Array.from( {length:X}, (v,i) => <span key={i} className="busterCards">♦</span> )
```

```
[...Array(3)].map( (_,i)=> <span key={i} className="busterCards">♦</span> )
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this (without lodash):

```
var numberOfCards = 8; // or more.

if (data.hand >= numberOfCards) {
    var cards = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
        cards[i] = (<span className="busterCards">♦</span>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array with as many items as you need rendered and then map through the array to render the correct number of elements you need.

```
const totalItems = 8;

const items = new Array(totalItems).fill(null);


// .... then
return (
    {items.map((_, idx) => <span className="busterCards" key = {idx}>♦</span>)}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was doing this today and came to this question and i think better approach is without creating an array and without any package. Which is recursion

```
const YourComp = ({ n }) => {
  if (n == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div className="py-8">
     do something
      <YourComp n={n - 1} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

cool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash [range](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range).

```js
_.range(20).map((_n, i) => <MyComponent key={i}/>)
```