# returning inside for loop breaks the loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a certain number of divs based on the `pageCount` value I have in my app. My approach is as follows

```
render() {
  const { pageCount } = this.props;
  function renderPages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
      return <div>{i}</div>;
    }
  }
  return <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{renderPages()}</div>;
}
```

So here `pageCount` value i get is 5. I want to render 5 divs but when returning, the loop breaks. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat an element n times using JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189370/how-to-repeat-an-element-n-times-using-jsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, your loop is breaking early due to the `return`. Instead, you can render an array of JSX. One way could be to create an array in your `renderPages` and `.push()` your `<div>`s into that:

```
function renderPages() {
  const divs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++){
    divs.push(<div>{i}</div>);
  }
  return divs;
}

return (
  <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
    {renderPages()}
  </div>
)
```

Or, you can populate an array using `Array.from()` with a mapping function:

```
function renderPages() {
  return Array.from({length: pageCount}, (_, i) => <div>{i}</div>);
}

return (
  <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
    {renderPages()}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning inside the for loop always breaks the loop. So instead you can use `.map` Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
render(){
    const {pageCount} = this.props;
    function renderPages(){
        return new Array(pageCount).map((item, index) => (
            <div>{item}</div>
        ));
    }
    return (
        <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
            {renderPages()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `pageCount` appears to be a number, not an array

Comment: Yes. pageCount is not an array. It's a number