# Need to loop the Icon and display Star Icon 5 times using React

Tags: reactjs

I have a Star Icon, I need to display the Icon for 5 Times..
So this is what I did, I Imported that Icon and stored in one constant, After that I displayed 5 times in that Div.........
But here I need to give Default value as 5 and Loop the Icon, Instead of displaying for 5 times.. Can anyone Help me in this, Thanks in Advance

```
Import {ReactComponet as Stars } from "assests/icons/star";
   
const starIcon = () => {
    const starIcon = <Stars />;
        
    return (
        <div>
            {starIcon } {starIcon } {starIcon } {starIcon } {starIcon }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, you want to render number of times depending on an argument N instead of hardcoded "5"?

Comment: Yes Exactly, Give some Solution for that

Comment: @DennisVash , Can You give some Solution for that

Comment: The duplicate upvoted answer is enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438518/7882470, just use your component instead