# How to add multiple whitespaces in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, whitespace

I am using React/JSX, I want to add **multiple** whitespaces depending on a condition, here is the element `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>`, I want to achieve effect like this in the broswer

```
HELLO         WORLD
```

I tried using `{' '}`, but it only add **a single** whitespace no matter how many spaces typed inside the quotes, for example, `<h1>HELLO {"       "} WORLD</h1>` still got

```
HELLO WORLD
```

I know we could use multiple `&nbsp;` like `<h1>HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WORLD</h1>`, but I need to **calculate** the number of whitespaces like `&nbsp; * my_variable` so I can't hardcode it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML produced by your React app includes the white-space. You can verify this by inspecting the element with your browsers developer tools. The white-space is [collapsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#collapsing_of_white_space) by the browser when rendering the page, so this is more of a HTML/CSS than a React feature.

To render white-space inside an element without them being collapsed, you could use [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property with `pre` or `pre-wrap` value.

```css
.preserve-white-space {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="preserve-white-space">HELLO          WORLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As [@kangasta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662732/how-to-add-multiple-whitespaces-in-jsx/76662782?noredirect=1#comment135162228_766627820) pointed out in the comments, you can use the [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function on a `\u00a0`, [the unicode value of NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

```
{'\u00a0'.repeat(spaces)}
```

---

**Original**: You could [create an array of n items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189370/how-to-repeat-an-element-n-times-using-jsx-and-lodash), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over them, and let it return a [`<React.Fragment>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment) with a `&nbsp;` inside it:

```
{[...Array(spaces)].map(e => <React.Fragment>&nbsp;</React.Fragment>)}
```

---

Demo showing both solutions mentioned above, press the button to increase the number of spaces.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [spaces, setSpaces] = useState(5);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            
            {/* str repeat */}
             <h3>
                {'Hello'}
                {'\u00a0'.repeat(spaces)}
                {'World'}
            </h3>
            
            {/* Array + Map */}
            <h3>
                {'Hello'}
                {[...Array(spaces)].map(e => <React.Fragment>&nbsp;</React.Fragment>)}
                {'World'}
            </h3>
            
            <button onClick={() => setSpaces(p => p + 1)}>Increase spacing</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: `'\u00a0'.repeat(spaces)` would also work for repeating the `&nbsp;` characters

Comment: @kangasta Your comment should be accepted!

Comment: Thanks @kangasta, I've included it in my answer.