# how can i manipulate a nav element with many nav links using forEach method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, foreach

Below is the code that I am trying to convert.

```
  document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
  for (const l of links) l.classList.toggle('scrolling', window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

the thing is, I intend to change the color of all my links when the page is scrolling.
That said, I could have used an if-else statement instead, but using an if-else statement would only
make the color of the first link to change instead. so forEach statement is the most appropriate method.

**The above code was converted to react like this as shown below.**

```
const [isLinkScrol, setIsLinkScrol] = useState(false);

const linkScroll = setLinkScrol(
   for (const l of links) l.classList.toggle( window.scrollY > 0);
);

      useEffect(() => {

        document.addEventListener('scroll', linkScroll);


        return () => { 
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', linkScroll);
              
            };

      },[]);

return (

<ul className={`nav_links ${isNavShowing ? "show_nav" : "hide_nav"}`}>
                {
                    links.map(({name, path }, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <NavLink to={path} className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active-nav" : ""}  onClick={() => setIsNavShowing (prev => !prev)}>{name}</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        )   
                    })
                }
            </ul>

)
```

**however, there seams to be an error here,**

```
setIsLinkScrol(
   for (const l of links) l.classList.toggle( window.scrollY > 0);
);
```

**which I have not been able to wrap my head around**

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `setLinkScroll`? You are not setting any value to is. You should set the scoll position to a state, which triggers a rerender and then apply styling if needed.

Comment: sorry for the typo, **(const [isLinkScrol, setIsLinkScrol] = useState(false);)** it has been corrected,  however it still persist

Comment: That typo doesn't cahnge anything. Still very unclear what you're trying to save in the useState. Could you add a [mre]?

Comment: ok, what I am trying to do is to toggle the scrolling css when the page scroll is greater than 0.

**so when scrolled the setIsLinkScrol() should add the scrolling css**

Comment: Your way of setting setIslInkScoll can't work. I've posted an example where the text gets a `scolling` class (orange text) when scroll is above 0. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the `setIsLinkScrol` setter to `addEventListener` as you will set the complete Event to the state, you don't want/need that.

Instead, make a `onScoll` function that will cal `setState` with `window.scrollY`.

Then you can add a `className` to some element(s) if the `scollValue > 0`

---

Small demo:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [scollValue, setScrollValue] = useState(0);

    const onScroll = (e) => setScrollValue(window.scrollY);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {[...Array(50)].map((e, i) => (
                <span className={scollValue > 0 ? 'scrolling' : ''} key={i}>Some content</span>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column }
.scrolling { color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

```
{[...Array(50)].map((e, i) => (
    <span className={scollValue > 0 ? 'scrolling' : ''} key={i}>Some content</span>
))}
```

Here I use `[...Array(50)].map` to create the same element 50 times
[How to repeat an element n times using JSX and Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189370/how-to-repeat-an-element-n-times-using-jsx-and-lodash)

Then we use an [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) to set the class if needed.

Comment: Perfect, I have been able to detect scroll events. However, there is an area of confusion. which is on the return element...

Comment: This is my element
`<ul className={`nav_links ${isNavShowing ? "show_nav" : "hide_nav"}`}>
                {
                    links.map(({name, path }, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <NavLink to={path} className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active-nav" : ""}  onClick={() => setIsNavShowing (prev => !prev)}>{name}</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        )   
                    })
                }
            </ul>`

Comment: Please edit your question to paste it there, it's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: kindly disregard the other element here, which is because I already have a function that shows when the link should been shown or hidden in mobile view.

Comment: instead where my links are nested is the li, I also already have some state as well.

Comment: so please, how can I nest yours here?

Comment: `{[...Array(50)].map((e, i) => (
                <span className={scollValue > 0 ? 'scrolling' : ''} key={i}>Some content</span>
            ))}`

Comment: I;ve added some explantion with a link to the answer. hope it helps.

Comment: ok, edited..
where my links are is in the `<li>....</li>