# I'm facing issues generating TSX react components with for loops

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I was learning the basics of ReactJS by creating a tic-tac-toe game and the board was initialy developed as bellow:

```
<div className="board-row">
    <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(0)} />
    <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(1)} />
    <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(2)} />
</div>
```

... and so on another 2 times.

Here's the Square component and its Props:

```
interface SquareProps {
  value: string;
  onSquareClick: () => void;
}
function Square({ value, onSquareClick }: SquareProps) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

When I click on each Square component, an `onClick` function is triggered passing the respective "id" of the clicked Square and then it is filled with the `value` Prop, that can be an "X" or an "O", depending on the respective index of the `squares` array passed.

Now I was trying to do this without all that hardcode, just using for loops.

I wrote the following function, but the Square Props `value` and `onSquareClick` didn't work on each Square component as they should like the previous code above.

```
const generateBoard = () => {
    const colsArr = Array(3);
    const cellsArr = Array(3);
    let cellId = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < cellsArr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < colsArr.length; j++) {
        colsArr[j] = (
          <Square
            key={j}
            value={squares[cellId]}
            onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(cellId)}
          />
        );
        cellsArr[i] = (
          <div key={i} className="board-row">
            {colsArr}
          </div>
        );
        cellId++;
      }
    }

    return cellsArr;
};
```

With that code, I can display the 3x3 board, but, when clicking on the first square, for example, then the 4th and the 7th (two bellow) got checked too and I want to avoid it.

Comment: please describe exactly what wasnt working? there are many issues here, but if you can specify what didnt work you are making it easier to help fix

Comment: With that code, I can display the 3x3 board, but, when clicking on the first square, for example, then the 4th and the 7th (two bellow) got checked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing data and views. Instead your views should be driven by your data. Additionally, I would avoid using for-loops altogether in React and instead rely on `Array.map`, and use hooks to prevent data being unnecessarily re-initialized.

Let's start by defining our data:

```
const data = useMemo(() => {
  return [...Array(3)].map((_, index) => [...Array(3)])
}, []);
```

Here we are creating an array with 3 items. Note that by spreading (`...`) the array into an array we have made it iterable (so we can call `.map` and other iteration methods on it).

Then we're using `.map` to iterate over this array and create another array of 3 items within each of the outer array items.

This results in something like:

```
[
  [undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined]
]
```

I've wrapped this initialization within a `useMemo` hook so that it won't be re-run, but you could also define this outside of your component without `useMemo` if the content will never change and doesn't rely on any local variables of the component, or put this in a `useState`/`useReducer` if you may later update the data.

Now we have some data we can iterate over it and create some components. This can be done straight inside the returned JSX of our component:

```
return (
  <>
    {data.map((_, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="board-row">
        {i.map((_, j) => (
          <Square key={j} value={j} onClick={() => handleSquareClick(j)} />
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Here we are first returning a React fragment `<></>` as you cannot return plain arrays in React components. Then within the fragment we're first iterating over our `data` and rendering a `div` for each item, and then within this div iterating over each sub-item and rendering a `Square` with values matching the items we're iterating over.

Note that at both levels we are applying a `key` so that React can track the items. At the moment we're just using the index for each item's `key`, but this is generally bad practice and it would be better if each item had a unique ID that can be used as the `key`.

Comment: I got the hint about use Arrays and the map() method, thank you very much, I'm a begginer at React development and it will help a lot!!

But the real problem now is pass an specific number to each Square component to fill the value and onSquareClick props. As there as nine squares, each one needs to receive an specific number from 0 to 9 respectively.

Comment: The second problem was solved by passing the rowIndex mutiplied by 3 and summed with the columnIndex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[...Array(n)].map()` to render an element n times, and use the index provided by `map()` to pass to the onClick:

- [How to repeat an element n times using JSX and Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189370/how-to-repeat-an-element-n-times-using-jsx-and-lodash)

---

So

```js
<div className="board-row">
    <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(0)} />
    <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(1)} />
    <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(2)} />
</div>
```

Can be re-written as

```
<div className="board-row">
    {
        [...Array(n)].map((e, i) => (
            <Square value={squares[i]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(i)} />
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Regarding the 3 rows, no need to make you DOM more complicated, I'd use a Flexbox to wrap it after 3 elements:

- [How to specify an element after which to wrap in css flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574851/how-to-specify-an-element-after-which-to-wrap-in-css-flexbox)

---

Small React Demo to show this :

```js
function Square({ value, index, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value} on index {index}
    </button>
  );
}

const Example = () => {

    const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' ]);
    
    const handleSquareClick = (n) => console.info('Pressed button', n);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <div className="board">
                {
                    [...Array(9)].map((e, i) => (
                        <Square value={squares[i]} onSquareClick={() => handleSquareClick(i)} index={i} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.board {
    width: 150px;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.board > .square {
    flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I think the point of the tic tac toe board is to have a 3x3 grid, which is why the wrapper row element is probably important.

Comment: I'd do that CSS way, no need to make your react more compliacted

Comment: I got the hint about use Arrays and the map() method, thank you very much, I'm a begginer at React development and it will help a lot!! But the real problem now is pass an specific number to each Square component to fill the value and onSquareClick props. As there as nine squares, each one needs to receive an specific number from 0 to 9 respectively.

Comment: Ive added it as a prop, that's the iterator from the map function. I've used it to find matching index in the value array, but now also passing to the deeper component to show you. Hope it helps.