# React Bootstrap Table can't create TableHeaderColumn with map Error. No any key column defined in TableHeaderColumn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap-table

I get the following error when I try to create `TableHeaderColumn` programatically using map.

> Uncaught Error: Error. No any key column defined in TableHeaderColumn.
>   Use 'isKey={true}' to specify a unique column after version 0.5.4.

If I don't use map and hard code the same values everything works. I usually use map for tables and it usually works as a charm. I have tried with and without `key` property for map, same error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647392/3850405

Does not work:

```
type TableHeader = {
    dataField: string;
    name: string
    isKey: boolean
}

const crimeTableHeaders: TableHeader[] = [{
    dataField: 'CrimeCode',
    name: 'Brottskod',
    isKey: true,
},
{
    dataField: 'CrimeCodeClearText',
    name: 'Namn',
    isKey: false,
},
{
    dataField: 'Count',
    name: 'Antal',
    isKey: false,
}
]

<BootstrapTable containerStyle={{ marginTop: '10px' }} data={this.props.data} options={this.options} striped={true} hover={true} search multiColumnSearch strictSearch>
    {crimeTableHeaders.map((tableHeader, index) => {
        <TableHeaderColumn key={index} dataField={tableHeader.dataField} isKey={tableHeader.isKey} dataSort={true}>{tableHeader.name}</TableHeaderColumn>
        /*<TableHeaderColumn dataField={tableHeader.dataField} isKey={tableHeader.isKey} dataSort={true}>{tableHeader.name}</TableHeaderColumn>*/
    })}
</BootstrapTable>
```

Works:

```
<BootstrapTable containerStyle={{ marginTop: '10px' }} data={this.props.data} options={this.options} striped={true} hover={true} search multiColumnSearch strictSearch>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='CrimeCode' isKey={true} dataSort={true}>Brottskod</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='CrimeCodeClearText' isKey={false} dataSort={true}>Namn</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='Count' isKey={false} dataSort={true}>Antal</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: you are not returning from the map.

Comment: @bennygenel This is why you should stop after 14h programming... Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. glad that I could help. If you like you can delete the question since its a typographical error.

Comment: @bennygenel You are to fast, saw it now. If I removed `{}` after my arrow function I did not need a return either.

Comment: removing `{}` is equal to doing `{return 'something'}` its a ES6 shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This API is the solution for you
[React bootstrap table - keyField](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#keyField)

```
<BootstrapTable data={ data } keyField='CrimeCode'>
  //Map function 
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)