# Most efficient (compact) way to create repetitive arrays in javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, repeat

Suppose I need an array with a number of repetitive elements, like this:

`[3,3,3,3,3,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5]` (so that's five 3s, four 8s, and six 5s)

In python, you can define this very elegantly like this:

```py
[3]*5+[8]*4+[5]*6
```

Are there similar constructions in JS or PHP?

In this example, defining the entire array explicitly isn't that much of a problem. But if there are many elements, with lots of repetitions, this can become very tedious (not to mention prone). I want my code size to stay equal, regardless of whether the array has five 3s or five hundred.

In JS, the shortest I can think of is:

```js
var a = [];
[[3,5],[8,4],[5,6]].forEach(function(x){while(x[1]--)a.push(x[0])});
```

Similar in PHP:

```
foreach(array(3=>5,8=>4,5=>6) as $d=>$n) while($n--) $a[]=$d;
```

Obviously this doesn't score bonus points for readability. Is there a better way (preferably some language construct) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

- *Array "addition"* is done through [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- There is no native *Array "multiplication"*

The best way for readability and re-usability is probably to define a *function* for *Array "multiplication"*, for example this one does it exponentially

```
function arrMultiply(arr, i) {
    var arr_out = [];
    if (i & 1)
        arr_out = arr_out.concat(arr);
    while ((i >>>= 1) > 0) {
        arr = arr.concat(arr);
        if (i & 1)
            arr_out = arr_out.concat(arr);
    }
    return arr_out;
}
```

Now you can *concat* together *"multiplied" Arrays*

```
arrMultiply([3], 5).concat(arrMultiply([8], 4)).concat(arrMultiply([5], 6));
// [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

---

If you really want to, you can extend the *prototype* of *Array* to include the `arrMultiply` *function* which would give you syntax closer to what you're already using,

```
Array.prototype.mul = function (i) {return arrMultiply(this, i);};

[3].mul(5).concat([8].mul(4)).concat([5].mul(6));
// [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: In this answer I called the operation _"multiplication"_ as we're implementing a behaviour of `*` from _Python_, but re-reading this answer I think it may be better to use the word _repeat_ instead, as _multiply_ can be ambiguous in this context (think _scalar multiplication, dot product, cross product, repetition, etc_)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(c)).map(function () {
    return v;
});
```

```js
function f(c, v) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(c)).map(function () {
        return v;
    });
}

document.write(f(5, 3).concat(f(4, 8)).concat(f(6, 5)));
```

---

".apply()" allows to pass arguments to a function in the form of an array, roughly:

```
say.apply(null, ['hello', 'world'])
```

Is the same as:

```
say('hello', 'world')
```

Hence, since `Array(3)` gives `[undefined x 3]`:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(3))
```

Is the same as:

```
Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)
```

Why is it required? Refer to [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501581/1636522).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to fill up an array with the values and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) it into your results array, e.g.

```
<?php

    $arr = [[3,5],[8,4],[5,6]];
    $result = [];
    foreach($arr as $v)
        $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, $v[1], $v[0]));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 5
    [10] => 5
    [11] => 5
    [12] => 5
    [13] => 5
    [14] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A freaky one (numbers only) x-)

```js
document.write(
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(
    makeArray('[1x1,3x4,42x3]')
  ) + '</pre>'
);

function makeArray (expr) {
  return JSON.parse(
    expr.replace(/(\d+)x(\d+)/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
      return $1 + new Array(+$2).join(','+$1);
    })
  );
}
```