# .map not working as expected on uninitiated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using `.map()` on an array full of undefined values (eg `new Array(10)`) will always return an array of the same length with undefined values, no matter what you return.

```
new Array(10).map(function(){return 5;});
```

will return a new array filled with 10x undefined. Why does this happen?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: FYI this happens in both Google Chrome as well as NodeJS, so I think it's not an implementation-specific bug.

Comment: It's not a bug if it's documented :)

Comment: @TudorConstantin well, if we're being pedantic, I never said it is a bug :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you define an array like that, the spaces for values are *empty slots* and are not iterated over by `map()` or any of its friends.

There is `Array.prototype.fill()` (in ES6) which can be used to set values on that array.

Comment: So they are returned as-is, without executing the callback function? Bonus points for the `fill()` recommendation!

Comment: @RenéRoth The function just does nothing, but it will return a new array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map(function(){ return 5; });
```

```js
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 10 }).map(function() { return 5; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

from [the fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

*map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined. It is **not called for missing elements of the array** (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).*

```
new Array(10)
```

creates missing elements, if that makes any sense.

Like this one:

```
var b=new Array();
b[30] = 1;
var c = b.map(function(){return 5;});

> [undefined × 30, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501711/6206601. Look at the top comment for further clarification.