# Use forEach to loop over Array(n), array of undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm want to quickly construct an array of `n` length using the array constructor `Array()` and then loop over the resulting array.

Per [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with length set to that number. If the argument is any other number, a
>   RangeError exception is thrown.

Presumably, executing `Array(5)` creates an array with a length of 5, which it does.

```js
var arr = new Array(5);

console.log(arr); // [undefined x 5]
console.log(arr.length); // 5
```

However, when I try to loop over the resulting array and log out the values or the index, nothing happens.

```
arr.forEach(function(v, i) { console.log(v, i); });

// nothing logs to the console
```

Alternatively, if I use an array literal, and try to loop over the values, it logs as expected:

```js
[undefined, undefined].forEach(function(v, i) { console.log(v, i); });

// undefined 0
// undefined 1
```

**Why can't I loop over an array created by the Array constructor?**

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness) explains some of the browser strangeness that occurs with `map`, example:

```
arr.map(function(v, i) { return i; }) // returns [undefined x 5]
```

But I'm particularly interested in why the `forEach` loop *doesn't iterate at all* over the values.

Comment: `[,,].forEach(console.log.bind(console, 'Log: '))` also seems broken :)

Comment: But `Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).forEach(console.log.bind(console))` ok

Comment: This is the same as [JavaScript “new Array(n)” and “Array.prototype.map” weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501581/1529630), but with `forEach`.

Comment: That question helps explain some of the strangeness, but doesn't illuminate the reason why `forEach` fails to iterate at all, as opposed to `map` which does iterate, but has unexpected values.

Comment: It's the same problem, `map` is not iterated neither: `Array(5).map(function(){ alert("You won't see me") })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand I am not answering to the question directly, bit still I believe this provides good information.

[Check what Kyle Simpson said recently about this topic.](https://youtu.be/2pL28CcEijU?t=17m18s)

Basically,

```
console.log(new Array(5))  // Chrome: [undefinedx5] Firefox: [ <5 empty slots> ]
```

and

```
console.log([undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]) // [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

are entirely different value types. And the browser is (kind of) lying to you when it says undefinedx5. Applying .map() over the first case will return nothing, while in the second case you can do operations with the undefined.

From the spec, [ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2), the only thing `new Array(5)` does, is to create an object of class type Array with length property = 5. The literal array syntax, [], actually places the types (if you give it something) in the slots.

Comment: can't you add short explanation here, about what he say?

Comment: If you use `JSON.stringify()` on the new Array object, you should get a sequence of nulls. I think that is worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

That's because ES5 array methods skip missing indexes. That is, they iterate `i` from `0` to `length-1`, but at each iteration they check if the array has an `i` own property.

If you want it to work, you can use `fill` to create the indices.

```js
var arr = new Array(5).fill();
arr.forEach(function(v, i) { console.log('arr['+i+'] = ' + v); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo in your code:

```
arr.forEach(functio(v, i) {
```

Use this instead:

```
arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
```

**UPDATE**

forEach() executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays). [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the typo and fixed it. The problem still exists, however.

Comment: just a typo. issue is there.

Comment: Updated the answer. For each skips over undefined properties

Comment: Knew it was forEach!  Thanks for doing the legwork and looking the details of it up.

Comment: it's actually don't skip real `undefined`s

Comment: Array.map seems to have similarly strange behavior, running `arr.map(function(v, i) { return i; });` returns `[undefined x 5]` rather than the proper indices. Whereas running the same map call on an array literal with `undefined` works as expected. This leads me to believe it's an issue with the Array constructor array, not just the array methods themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I meant uninitialised. TBH I've never used forEach(), I tend to go for for(). This was an exercise in research for me

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that this may have to do with intricacies of the Javascript foreach loop, not the Array(int) constructor.  Using a normal for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(arr[i] + " " + i);
}
```

produced the desired result.