# Manufacturing an array - why is it different?

Tags: javascript, node.js

consider I declare two variables like this (done within REPL, with node v7.7.2), which I expect to be arrays:

```
var x = Array(4)
var y = Array.from({length: 4})
```

then the following should work identically, but it doesn't:

```
x.map(Math.random)
[ , , ,  ]
y.map(Math.random)
[ 0.46597917021676816,
  0.3348459056304458,
  0.2913995519428412,
  0.8683430009997699 ]
```

in looking, it seems x and y are both identical:

```
> typeof x
'object'
> typeof y
'object'
> Array.isArray(x)
true
> Array.isArray(y)
true
> x.length
4
> y.length
4
> typeof x[0]
'undefined'
> typeof y[0]
'undefined'
```

so why the difference?

Comment: `Object.keys(x)` vs `Object.keys(y)` is definitely the reason.

Comment: it would have never occurred to me to look for keys in an array (given as how isArray() returns true)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first three outputs, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description) works.

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

The ECMA 262 standard to [`Array.from`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from) describes a construction with length for a new array (point 7 ff).

```js
var x = Array(4),
    y = Array.from({ length: 4 }),
    arrayX = x.map(Math.random),
    arrayY = y.map(Math.random),
    z = Array.from({ length: 4 }, Math.random);

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(arrayX);
console.log(arrayY);
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it should not have the same results fot both cases. See the manual here about `Array`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with its length property set to that number (**Note: this implies an
>   array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined
>   values**). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception
>   is thrown.

And here about the `Array.from()` method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Check the following example on the page linked above:

```
// Generate a sequence of numbers
// Since the array is initialized with `undefined` on each position,
// the value of `v` below will be `undefined`
Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i);
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: so there's a difference between an "empty" slot and a slot that contains *undefined*? the last stanza in my code indicates that `typeof x[0] == typeof y[0]` is true.  so how can I get the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The Array created with Array(4) is not iterated over with .map(), whereas the Array.from({ length: 4 }) is iterated over. A fuller explanation can be found at [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness), you can test this with..

```
x.map((f,i) => console.log(i)) vs. y.map((f,i) => console.log(i))
```

Comment: in other words, this is an exact duplicate?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the cause of the issue was the same.