# why map a Array of `undefined` return a Array of `undefined`

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna create a function(m ,n){}, return a array, it's length of m, each value is `n`

```
function createArray(m, n){
  let a = new Array(6);
  return a.map(item => n)
}
const z = createArray(5,6);
console.log(z)
```

I supposed `z` will be a array of `6`
  why `z` is a array of `undefined`?

Comment: You are creating an array of length 6 with undefined values. `new Array(6)` does that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax

Comment: This has been answered quite a few times already.

Comment: `return [...a].map(item => n)`

Comment: @A.Akram it works, can u instruct why my style is not working a little bit?

Comment: @Liuuil, I'm not expert, but as I understand: `new Array(6)` has the same effect as `a=[]; a.length=6`. Which only sets the length without allocating real slots. it seems `map` iterate through "defined" slots not as you expect to iterate through 0 => array's length .

Answer (score 0):

`z` is indeed an array of 6, but 6 empty slot because your `new Array` does just create an empty array with 6 slots but no value

Pre ES6

```
let arr = new Array(10).fill('5');
```

You can check the link on top, speaking about this case ([JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness))

Comment: so how can  I create a array with 6 slots and value

Comment: just edited my answer with the solution