# Mapping Over a new Array() without populating it returns an empty array. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

## Riddle me this.

Let's say you new up an array of 1,000 elements and want to assign the index of each element as the element's value using `.map()`. I would expect it to work like so:

```
new Array(1000).map((element, i) => i);
```

Here's the problem: the new array returned, while having the required 1,000 elements, is empty, despite assigning the `.map()`'s return value to be the array index. This can be remedied by chaining `.fill(0)` like so:

```
new Array(1000).fill(0).map((element, i) => i);
```

## But why?

Why do `.map` or `.filter` require a populated array to produce a populated array?

Comment: Jared Smith, any chance of getting the article with the accepted answer retitled with something a little more descriptive of the contents of the question? I think my title's a little more search friendly than "weiredness."

Comment: What do you want it to be?

Comment: You're welcome to lift my title wholesale. I had a bummer of a time searching for the answer on this (hence the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mainly because the array must be filled, even with undefined pointers in order to be iterated. With `new Array()` it is not.

> From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (emphasis mine): "map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. The callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values."

According to the first comment of the accepted answer of this thread:

[JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Answer (score 4):

To make it working you can use the spread operator in ECMA6

```js
console.log([...new Array(1000)].map((element, i) => i))
```

Comment: …but for this purpose better use `Array.from({length: 1000}, (element, i) => i)`

Comment: Yeah, my example was scholastic. These examples are awesome though.