# Difference between new Array(7) and Array.apply(null, Array(7))

Tags: javascript, arrays

Anyone can explain me difference between `new Array(7)` and `Array.apply(null, Array(7))`? In context:

```js
Array.apply(null, Array(7)).map((e, i) => {
  return moment(i, 'e').format('ddd');
}); // ["Sun" ,"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

new Array(7).map((e, i) => {
  return moment(i, 'e').format('dd');
}); // [empty × 7]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when that codes runs. `"TypeError: (new Array(...)).apply is not a function",`

Comment: @user184994, edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Comment: check the link in the comment above. The top answer goes into exactly why this happens

Comment: no it's not I wanna know why Array.apply() work and new Array() doesn't work, why we should pass parameters(null and Array7)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Array(7)
```

creates a Sparse array with no elements set. So as an object it would look like:

```
 {length: 7}
```

If you would call any of the new cool array methods, it wouldnt iterate as there are no elements in the array. However if that is spread into the Array constructor:

```
  Array(...Array(3))
```

Its equal to

```
 Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)
```

And that actually creates 3 (or 7) undefined array slots:

```
 {
 0:undefined,
 1:undefined,
 2:undefined,
 length:3
 }
```

And now you can iterate over it with `map` etc. The same is possible with:

```
 Array(7).fill().map(func)
```

and

```
 Array.from({length:7}, func);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls the prototype method on the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object. Where as doing `Array(7)` is creating a new array of seven elements, as such `new Array(7).apply` is not a valid call and would give the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).apply is not a function

Doing `Array.apply(null, Array(7))` is the only valid call here.

**Edit**

The statement `Array.apply(null, Array(7))` will create an array populated with `undefined` elements. As such calling `.map()` will iterate those elements and produce your expected result.

On the other hand calling just `new Array(7)` will create a sparse array with a define length of `7`. Meaning the length will be defined as `7` but it didn't populate any elements into the array. So there is nothing to iterate over yet.

Comment: prototype method it is like static method?

Comment: `Array` is a function!

Answer (score 1):

these two approach are equivalent since [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is part of the `Function` api.

it looks you likely need something like:

```js
Array
  .from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => moment(i, 'e').format('ddd'))
;
```