# Merge Arrays in Javascript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I was wondering if there was a way to merge arrays in this way in javascript

`Array1 = ['1', '234', '56']`

`Array2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56']`

Wanted outcome = `['11', '2342', '5645', '56']`

Is there a way built into the language to do this?

Comment: yes.. there is a way

Comment: @MladenIlić, OP is asking for a way to merge elements, not how to concat.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, my bad.

Comment: You can add strings together, and you can iterate over the array with forEach or a for loop. What research have you done? Where's your attempt?

Comment: Good questions show that you've done some of your own research, show what you've tried and explain exactly where you got stuck.  You should not be using stackoverflow as a "please write this code for me" service.  stackoverflow should be used as a problem solving service when you've attempted to solve the problem yourself and you show what you've attempted to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another:

```js
const Array1 = ['1', '234', '56']
const Array2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'];
const merged = Array2.map((arr2elm, i) => (Array1[i] ? Array1[i] : '') + arr2elm);
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: What if array1 is bigger?

Comment: Then just reverse it, or do a test beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

No native feature for that, but here is a way to achieve it;

```js
var a1 = ['1', '234', '56'];
var a2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'];

var length = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length)
var merge = new Array(length).fill().map((el, index) => {
    return (a1[index] || '') + (a2[index] || '')
})

console.log(merge)
```

This code will provide you with the correct answer regardless of which array is bigger.

EDIT:

As per commenter suggestion, by using a for loop you wont waste memory resources by creating an array just for iteration purposes.

```js
    var a1 = ['1', '234', '56'];
    var a2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'];

    var length = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length)
    var merge = []
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      merge.push((a1[i] || '') + (a2[i] || ''))
    }

    console.log(merge)
```

And, even faster if you replace the `.push()` with an assignment:

```js
    var a1 = ['1', '234', '56'];
    var a2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'];

    var length = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);
    var merge = new Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      merge[i] = (a1[i] || '') + (a2[i] || '');
    }

    console.log(merge);
```

Comment: Why create an array filled with emptiness, then use `.map()` on it?  Might as well just use a `for` loop to populate a new array.

Comment: @jfriend00 have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness

Comment: Also, I suggest that you remove the call to `.fill()` and experience it yourself. The second option (to use a for loop instead) is in fact a lot better (considering memory consumption)

Comment: The point is that you're just wasting resources by creating a new array and then calling `.fill()` on it and never using it for anything except as an iterator for `.map()`.  I would think it is more efficient to just use a `for` loop with the `length` you already have to do an iteration without ever creating that temporary array at all.  From an efficiency point of view, you're creating an array you're never going to use the contents of, then iterating it twice.

Comment: The link you referenced has nothing to do with the meaning of my comments.  I'm talking about just using `for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)` instead of `new Array(length).fill().map()`.  It appears you don't yet understand my comment.

Comment: I first thought you were questioning why using `fill()`, the link I shared elaborates on that. Using a for loop is indeed better in terms of memory consumption. It is the second time that I agree with you.

Comment: OK, I upvoted now that you've added the second option.  In [a jsperf](https://jsperf.com/combine-contents-of-arrays), the second option is about 30% faster and if you preallocate the merge array and just assign `merge[i] = (a1[i] || '') + (a2[i] || '')` instead of use `.push()`, then it's about 50% faster.

Comment: Thank you for you contribution @jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using the function [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

The function [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) accepts three params:

- `arrayLike` An array-like or iterable object to convert to an array.
- `mapFn` Map function to call on every element of the array.
  **Optional**.
- `thisArg` Value to use as this when executing mapFn **Optional**.

This approach passes an object with the required property `length` (array-like or iterable object) with the max length from both arrays and the callback will provide two params:

- `value` (in this case is `undefined`) from an array
- The current `index`.

Basically, the callback concatenates two values and both operands check for the current value at a specific index because not necessarily the arrays have the same length.

```js
var arr1 = ['1', '234', '56'],
    arr2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'],
    newArray = Array.from({length: Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)}, 
                         (_, i) => ((arr1[i] || '') + (arr2[i] || '')));
//                        ^  ^
//                        |  |
//                        |  +---- This is the current index.
//                        |
//                        +---- In this case, the value is undefined
//                              and is unnecessary to accomplish your
//                              scenario.
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Some explanation of the code and how/why it works could make this a more useful answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 my bad!

Comment: Interesting use of `Array.from()`.  Never seen that before.  FYI, compared to the scenarios in Renato's answer and my comments below it, this solution turns out to be [pretty slow](https://jsperf.com/combine-contents-of-arrays) (80% slower than the best one there).  It is creative though.

Comment: @jfriend00 `:(` It's good to know about the performance.  `for-loops` are very fast!

Answer (score 1):

```
function mergeArrays(array1, array2) {
   const count = array1.length > array2.length 
      ? array1.length
      : array2.length;

   const result = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      result.push(`${ array1[i] || '' }${ array2[i] || '' }`);
   }

   return result;
}
```

A side-note: don't use uppercase naming for your identifiers unless they are classes.

Comment: You might want to check the outcome in the question again.

Comment: Read the question too quick  Updated answer.  This answer is with performance in mind (thus the for loop)

Comment: Why use a template string instead of just `+`?

Comment: @jfriend00 the reason being in case an item is a number, so we don't accidentally add the values rather than concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```js
let Array1 = ['1', '234', '56','11','11','22']; 
let Array2 = ['1', '2', '45', '56'];
let new_arr=[];
new_arr=Array1.map((object,i) => object + Array2[i]).concat(Array2.splice(Array1.length,1));
//remove undefined due to variable size
let new_arr_str=new_arr.join(",").replace(/undefined/g,'');
console.log(new_arr_str.split(","));
```

I have removed undefined variable if array1 is larger than array 1 using string functions

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, i fixed it but looks like a messy way. please correct me if  I am wrong