# Why do I need to copy an array to use a method on it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can use `Array()` to have an array with a fixed number of undefined entries. For example

```
Array(2); // [empty × 2]
```

But if I go and use the map method, say, on my new array, the entries are still undefined:

```
Array(2).map( () => "foo");  // [empty × 2]
```

If I copy the array then map does work:

```
[...Array(2)].map( () => "foo");  // ["foo", "foo"]
```

Why do I need a copy to use the array?

Comment: what is the result of `[...Array(2)]`

Comment: @Kain0_0 It is [undefined, undefined]. And Array.isArray(Array(2)) is true.

Comment: Can use `fill()` also. `Array(2).fill("foo"); // ["foo", "foo"]` Just have to be careful with passing object to fill as all elements will be same reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Comment: There's nothing like _index out of bound error_ in JavaScript.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you use `Array(arrayLength)` to create an array, you will [have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters):

> a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values).

The array does not actually contain any values, not even `undefined` values - it simply has a `length` property.

When you *spread* an iterable object with a `length` property into an array, spread syntax accesses each index and sets the value at that index in the new array. For example:

```js
const arr1 = [];
arr1.length = 4;
// arr1 does not actually have any index properties:
console.log('1' in arr1);

const arr2 = [...arr1];
console.log(arr2);
console.log('2' in arr2);
```

And `.map` only maps properties/values for which the property actually exists in the array you're mapping over.

Using the array constructor is confusing. I would suggest using `Array.from` instead, when creating arrays from scratch - you can pass it an object with a `length` property, as well as a mapping function:

```js
const arr = Array.from(
  { length: 2 },
  () => 'foo'
);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I saw `Array()` in a course and it reminded me of something useful in Python, But sadly it's maybe it's not so useful. Cheers.

Comment: It *used* to be a decent option, before `Array.from` was available, but now I don't think there's any reason to use it, it has too much potential for confusion.

Comment: Hey Need you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834433/how-to-promisify-using-providing-some-limit Pls

Answer (score 10):

The reason is that the array element is unassigned. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the first paragraph of the description. *... callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined.*

Consider:

```
var array1 = Array(2);
array1[0] = undefined;

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(array1);
console.log(map1);
```

Outputs:

```
Array [undefined, undefined]
Array [NaN, undefined]
```

When the array is printed each of its elements are interrogated. The first has been assigned `undefined` the other is defaulted to `undefined`.

The mapping operation calls the mapping operation for the first element because it has been defined (through assignment). It does not call the mapping operation for the second argument, and simply passes out `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @CertainPerformance, your array doesn't have any properties besides its `length`, you can verify that with this line: `new Array(1).hasOwnProperty(0)`, which returns `false`.

Looking at [15.4.4.19 Array.prototype.map](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19) you can see, at *7.3*, there's a check whether a *key* exists in the array.

1..6. [...]
7. Repeat,
        while *k* < *len*

1. Let
               *Pk* be ToString(*k*).
2. Let
               *kPresent* be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]]
               internal method of *O* with argument *Pk*.
3. If
               *kPresent* is **true**, then

   1. Let
                      *kValue* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal
                      method of *O* with argument *Pk*.
   2. Let
                      *mappedValue* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal
                      method of *callbackfn* with *T* as the **this**
                      value and argument list containing *kValue*, *k*, and
                      *O*.
   3. Call
                      the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *A* with
                      arguments *Pk*, Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: *mappedValue*,
                      [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true**,
                      [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.
4. Increase
               *k* by 1.

9. Return *A*.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, `Array(2)` will only create an array of two empty slots which cannot be mapped over.

As far as [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) are concerned, `Array(2)` is indeed an empty array:

```
Array(2).some(() => 1 > 0); //=> false
Array(2).every(() => 1 < 0); //=> true
```

However this array of empty slots can somehow be "iterated" on:

```
[].join(','); //=> ''
Array(2).join(','); //=> ','

JSON.stringify([]) //=> '[]'
JSON.stringify(Array(2)) //=> '[null,null]'
```

So we can take that knowledge to come up with interesting and somewhat ironic ways to use ES5 array functions on such "empty" arrays.

You've come up with that one yourself:

```
[...Array(2)].map(foo);
```

A variation of a suggestion from @charlietfl:

```
Array(2).fill().map(foo);
```

**Personally I'd recommend this one:**

```
Array.from(Array(2)).map(foo);
```

A bit old school:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(2)).map(foo);
```

This one is quite verbose:

```
Array(2).join(',').split(',').map(foo);
```