# javascript - when I create an array of empty items, I can't use map with it

Tags: javascript

I tried this

```
> Array(3)
[ <3 empty items> ]
> // and this joins up all the nothings
> Array(3).join('-')
'--'
> // but...
> Array(3).map((x) => 'a')
[ <3 empty items> ]
> // map doesn't work with the array of empty items!
```

and I thought I would get the same result as this

```
> [undefined, undefined, undefined].map((x) => 'a')
[ 'a', 'a', 'a' ]
```

What's up with that?

Comment: The `.map()` method (and others like it) skip uninitialized array positions.

Comment: Try `Array(3).fill(null).map(x => 'a')`

Comment: thanks! that's funny how join is cool with it

Comment: See: [Why do I need to copy an array to use a method on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491990)

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't even think how to _search_ for this!

Comment: yeah so join my be implemented by going through all the indices up to the length and asking for the value, while map is not

Comment: `Array(3).fill("a")`? There is also `Array.from({length: 3}, () => 'a')` (or `Array.from(Array(3), () => 'a')`) if you want to do something potentially more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the first case you creates an array with undefined pointers.

```
Array(3)
```

And the second creates an array with pointers to 3 undefined objects, in this case the pointers them self are NOT undefined, only the objects they point to.

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

when we compare the two case it's look like this

```
//first case look like this 
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
//the second look like this 
 Array(3) [,,,];
```

map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. In the first case array values have not explicitly assigned values, whereas in the seconds example were assigned, even if it was the value undefined [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

for you example you have to do this

```
Array(3).fill(undefined).map(x => 'a')
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use :

```
Array(3).fill(null).map(x => 'a')
```