# Array of length 1 is created when using new Array(20)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

My function is following

```
export const addressGenerator = (total: number, type: AllowedAddressTypes) => {
    console.log("creating total of", total)
    const f = getExecutable(type)
    const result = new Array(total).map(_ => f())
    console.log(result)
    return result
}
```

I call it as

```
addressGenerator(20, 'city')
```

What I see in logs is

```
creating total of 20
[ 'South Malloryburgh' ]
result 20 [ 'South Malloryburgh' ]
```

But always an array of `1` is created. When I hardcode the line

```
new Array(20).map(_ => f())
```

I do see an array of `20` being created. Given that `total` is of `number` type, I am wondering what am I missing?

Can anyone give me a fresh perspective?
Thank you

Comment: Try `[...Array(20)]` or `Array(20).fill()` before `map`.

Comment: Yes, that's expected.  It's why a lot of the answers in [javascript create empty array of a given size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246860/691711) have things like `Array(4).fill(null)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to copy an array to use a method on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491943/why-do-i-need-to-copy-an-array-to-use-a-method-on-it)

Comment: Probably a better dupe, if anyone has a gold badge: [JavaScript “new Array(n)” and “Array.prototype.map” weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill the array first, before you can map. Just because you designated a size for your array does not mean that the items exist in their positions yet.

```js
new Array(20).fill(null).map(_ => f())
```

Alternatively, you could call the following:

```js
Array.from(new Array(20), () => f())
```

or

```js
Array.from({ length: 20 }, f)
```

---

There is an extensive list of strategies for creating and manipulating arrays here:

> [*Hacks for Creating JavaScript Arrays*](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-gladchinda-hacks-for-creating-javascript-arrays-a1b80cb372b/)