# JS creating an array of 3 elements containing random number from 0 to 255 (included) in single line of code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array with 3 elements without using for loops, so the code will be a single line (or single statement). What I want to do is creating an array of 3 elements and each element should be random number from 0 to 255 (0 and 255 will be included).

```js
let colors = new Array(3).map((v) => Math.floor(Math.random()*256));
```

But this code doesn't work, I guess it's because each element is undefined and .map array property can't map undefined elements. What's your suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect `new Array()` to create 3 elements? (I'm guessing you may have forgotten to add `3` to `new Arrray(3)` and that you may be facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491943/why-do-i-need-to-copy-an-array-to-use-a-method-on-it/53491990#53491990)?)

Comment: @NickParsons Oh, yeah. I forgot it. I have tried that with ``new Array(3)``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is something you are looking for:

```js
const res = Array.from({length: 3}, _ => Math.floor(Math.random()*256))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know about .from array property. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) specifying the *array-like objects (objects with a length property and indexed elements)* of the array as first parameter and the arrow function to fill the array with random values in that range as the second parameter:

```js
let colors = Array.from({length: 3}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without usage of `Array.from`

```js
[0,0,0].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))
```

One more ridiculous approach :) just for fun:

```js
var result =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.pow(2, 24) + 1)) // generate random number between zero and 2^24
    .toString(2) // convert it to binary representation string
    .padStart(24, '0') // ensure that length is 24
    .match(/.{1,8}/g) // split digits to three groups of length 8
    .map(i => parseInt(i, 2)) // parse it back

console.log(result)
```

- 2^24 will have 24 digits in binary representation, so we'll be able to split it in 3 groups of 8 digits each.
- padding is necessary to ensure amount of digits in a binary representation

Answer (score 0):

Something less extensible but more **straight-forward**:

```js
let colors = [Math.floor(Math.random()*256),Math.floor(Math.random()*256),Math.floor(Math.random()*256)];
console.log(colors)
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty repetitive and straight-forward :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from({length: 3}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this, you'll be fine!

```js
const colors = Array.from({length: 5 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random()*256))

console.log(colors)
```