# Why an empty array of N length in javascript does not have indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have created an empty array in Javascript

```
const x = Array(5);
```

Or

```
const x = new Array(5);
```

And if i check the length, Its `5` in both the cases but when I loop over it using `.map` then it did not give me the indices i.e `0,1,2,3,4`

```
x.map((el, i) => i);
```

This should return `[0,1,2,3,4]`

Comment: And yes I have achieved this behaviour using `const x = Array.from(Array(5))` but just wanted to know the reason why above approach is not working.

Comment: update your question. a comment is a comment

Comment: see also ... [No operation for uninitialized values (sparse arrays)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#no_operation_for_uninitialized_values_sparse_arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [the specification requires](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array) that when an array is created like that with the Array constructor, where `values` is the argument list:

```
a. Let len be values[0].
b. Let array be ! ArrayCreate(0, proto).
c. If Type(len) is not Number, then
  i. Perform ! CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(array, "0", len).
  ii. Let intLen be 1.
d. Else,
  i. Let intLen be ! ToUint32(len).
  ii. If SameValueZero(intLen, len) is false, throw a RangeError exception.
e. Perform ! Set(array, "length", intLen, true).
f. Return array.
```

That's all it does, and nothing else. In short, it creates a new array object inheriting from `Array.prototype`, and then sets a `length` property on it. It doesn't create any numeric indicies on the array.

It's like

```js
const createArray = (length) => {
  const newArr = Object.create(Array.prototype);
  newArr.length = length;
  return newArr;
};

const arr = createArray(5);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('0'));
```

As a result, if you want to iterate over the array, you'll have to fill it first somehow - either with `.fill`, `Array.from`, or [spreading it into a new array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491943/why-do-i-need-to-copy-an-array-to-use-a-method-on-it).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer this is really helpful. Can you also explain where this is useful? I mean a practical use-case?

Comment: I suppose, in rare cases, one would like to create an array with a given large length without also filling all those indicies with values. But that'd be really strange. It's best practice to avoid sparse arrays in all circumstances. I think, if the language was re-designed today, this behavior would be re-examined - it causes far more confusion than the benefits it provides.