# How do I get an Array item's opposite index and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, range, indexof

I have an array that I created using `Array(...)` and `Array.prototype.map`, like this:

```
var array_name = Array(255).map(function(undef, i) {
  return i + 1;
});
```

The values of this array are:

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., 253, 254, 255]
```

This is an array that won't get modified, so the first value of this array will always be `1` and the last value of this array will always be `255`.

I already know the index of each value is `{value} - 1`, so `200` would be `199`, `199` would be `198`, so on and so forth.

Let's say I want `255`'s opposite value, which would be `0`, I could get that using `array_name[0]`, but what if I wanted `200`'s opposite value, how would I know what the opposite index of `199` is so I could get it's value?

Comment: do you have an example what you like to do (in code form)?

Comment: You can use `reverse()` for opposite index

Comment: Whoops. Yes, the opposite value for `255` is `0`, it was an honest mistake and I fixed it.

Comment: array_name[(array_name.length-1) - index]

Comment: @NinaScholz Are you asking if I can create sample code to produce the desired result? If so, that won't be possible because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @LogicalBranch Just an example array and the desired output

Comment: @MaheerAli You're suggestion also worked, [thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198181/10415695).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
opposite_index = arr.length - index - 1
```

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

index = 3
a[index]
4
```

It's opposite is 7 so:

```
opposite_index = a.length - index - 1
a[opposite_index]
7
```

With `reverse` as per @Maheer Ali suggestion:

```
a.reverse()[index]
7
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you gotta understand that there is weird behavior concerning `Array(n).map(f)` (it won't create the array you're expecting), [see this answer for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35086350/6275103), second, do this to get the opposite values:

```js
/* fill it first with .fill(), see the question I linked for more explanation */
var array = Array(255).fill(undefined).map(function(undef, i) {
  return i + 1;
});

function opposite(array, n) {
  return array[array.length - n];
}

console.log(opposite(array, 255));
console.log(opposite(array, 200));
console.log(opposite(array, 199));
console.log(opposite(array, 1));
```

Notice that `length - n` is used instead of `length - n - 1`, because we're dealing with values from `1` to `n`, not from `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer this question, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your  `Array(255).map()` create undefined array value.So do with `Array#from` length object.And pass your value.get index of the value and match with reverse array you get opposite value

```js
let check = (val) => {
var array_name = Array.from({length:255},(a,b)=>b+1);
var nor_ind = array_name.indexOf(val);
var re_in = array_name.reverse(array_name).indexOf(val)
return ({nor_val:val,nor_ind:nor_ind,opp_val:re_in})
}

console.log(check(254))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code you provided doesn't create array `[1,2,3...255]`. It will create it will 255 empty items first you need to `fill()`.

```js
var arr = Array(255).fill().map((a,i) => i+1);


//Create an array which will have revese items.
let revarr= arr.reverse()
console.log(revarr[0]) //255
console.log(revarr[254]) // 1
```

If you don't want to create a reverse arr. You can create a `function`

```js
var arr = Array(255).fill().map((a,i) => i+1);
const opp = (arr,num) => arr[arr.length - num - 1];
console.log(opp(arr,0));
console.log(opp(arr,254));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer this question and thank you for the suggestion, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the **index** from *(length-1)* -> **max inde**x of the array

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function findOpp(index, length) {
  maxIndex = length - 1;
  if (index <= maxIndex && index >= 0) {
    return maxIndex - index;
  } else {
    
    return 'You have enter a wrong index';
  }
}

console.log(findOpp(-1, 10));
console.log(findOpp(0, 10));
console.log(findOpp(1, 10));
console.log(findOpp(2, 10));
console.log(findOpp(4, 10));
console.log(findOpp(5, 10));
console.log(findOpp(6, 10));
console.log(findOpp(7, 10));
console.log(findOpp(8, 10));
console.log(findOpp(9, 10));
console.log(findOpp(10, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Maheer Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9819146/maheer-ali)'s suggestion I managed to get the desired result by reversing the array and using `indexOf` to  get the index of that number:

```
var numbers = Array(255).map(function(v, i) {
  return i + 1;
});

var opposite_brightness = numbers.reverse()[numbers.indexOf(brightness)];
```