# How to create an array with certain variable length and the same value repeated without using .fill?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm creating a graph thanks to Chart.js, in a project of ASP.NET MVC, and in the view, I need to create an array with a value, but the length of the array is variable, I used the ".fill" and worked great, but in IE11 doesn't work so I need another way.

I have been searching the web but I haven't found any clean way to do it, and my knowledge is very limited because I have just started working with JS.

This is what I was using but doesn't work on IE11

```
var arrayBackgroundColor = Array(@Model.Data.Count()).fill('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)');
```

(the @Model.Data.Count() is an integer corresponding with the length it must have)

This is the answer from IE11 on the console error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fill'
```

So, I would really appreciate another way of creating the desired array.

Comment: You could fill it with a loop.

Comment: I thought about that but if the array is too big it would affect performance, right? I was searching for something cleaner like .fill() @Lewis

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array?rq=1#answer-44726020 . This example uses `.concat` and `.slice`. Both are supported by IE11 (even lowers), this may be an easily reusable solution. https://jsfiddle.net/aLh2fbkz/ . otherwise, use `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal for loop

```
let arrayBackgroundColor =[]; 

for(var i = 0;i<@Model.Data.Count();i++){
  arrayBackgroundColor .push('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)')
});
```

or you can use this [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill)

Comment: thought about that but if the array is too big it would affect performance, right? I was searching for something cleaner like .fill()

Comment: @MiguelCordero you can check the polyfil and  `for..` loop is elementary, Even in the polyfil which is created by mdn , is using a `while` loop

Comment: thanks, I used and it works as expected

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
var arrayBackgroundColor = Array.apply(null, Array(@Model.Data.Count())).map(function(e) {
    return 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)';
});
```

Comment: You mean the arrow function @Lewis? I'll fix that.

Comment: Nope - http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array_methods_Array.prototype.map_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;

Comment: That's the link from CanIUse by the way.

Comment: You were looking at `flat` and `flatMap` (and possibly the `Map` object which is different).

Comment: My bad, will remove my comment =)

Comment: [this does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Comment: My apologies @Bergi - I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited my answer - any better? (I have tested it and it works)

Answer (score 1):

Polyfill .fill()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill

```
if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'fill', {
    value: function(value) {

      // Steps 1-2.
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
      }

      var O = Object(this);

      // Steps 3-5.
      var len = O.length >>> 0;

      // Steps 6-7.
      var start = arguments[1];
      var relativeStart = start >> 0;

      // Step 8.
      var k = relativeStart < 0 ?
        Math.max(len + relativeStart, 0) :
        Math.min(relativeStart, len);

      // Steps 9-10.
      var end = arguments[2];
      var relativeEnd = end === undefined ?
        len : end >> 0;

      // Step 11.
      var final = relativeEnd < 0 ?
        Math.max(len + relativeEnd, 0) :
        Math.min(relativeEnd, len);

      // Step 12.
      while (k < final) {
        O[k] = value;
        k++;
      }

      // Step 13.
      return O;
    }
  });
}
```