# Why Array().splice doesn't work for inserting value at index?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a passcode or OTP input modal to verify the user's email and phone number.

```html
<form>
 <span id="ap-email-otp" class="actions-pack-otp">
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="0" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="1" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="2" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="3" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="4" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="email" data-index="5" maxlength="1" required>
 </span>
 <span id="ap-phone-otp" class="actions-pack-otp">
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="0" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="1" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="2" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="3" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="4" maxlength="1" required>
   <input type="tel" class="ap-otp-input" data-channel="phone" data-index="5" maxlength="1" required>
 </span>
</form>
```

[image]
I want to update an object `otp` on every `keyup` event.

```js
otp = {};

$document.on('keyup', '.ap-otp-input', function (e){

    if( e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37 ){
        $(this).prev(':input').focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(':input').focus();
    }

    otp[$(this).attr('data-channel')] = Array(6).splice( $(this).attr('data-index'), 0, $(this).val());

});
```

**Output Getting:**

```js
otp{
  email : [], // Empty array
  phone : [], // Empty array
}
```

**Expected Output**
Value of input should be inserted at it's data index.

Note : The "channel" names i.e email, phone etc are not predictable. It is dynamically calculated from the input's data-channel attribute.

Comment: `Array(6)` creates an **empty** array of length 6; what is it that you expect the splice to do?

Comment: I wanted to insert the value of an individual input at a specific index that is calculated from its data-index attribute.

Comment: But `Array(6)` creates a **new** array in that statement, and you overwrite the previous value. I don't think you need `.splice()` at all.

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the deleted items from the array. Why are you using splice on empty array?

Comment: @Pointy Yes I wanted to create an array dynamically. Could you please tell me an alternative solution to update the value of each object?

Comment: @adiga right, and because 0 elements are removed, that always returns an empty array.

Comment: @adiga first of all I don't think that is an empty array. It is an array of undefined like [undefined, undefined, undefined.....] I just want to update the value in a particular index. The index is calculated from this.att('data-index')

Comment: `Array(6)` creates an array with *holes* (`[empty × 6]`) and this is not the same as assigning undefined values to each index like `Array.from({ length: 6 })`. For example: [JavaScript “new Array(n)” and “Array.prototype.map” weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `otp` with two empty arrays:

```
otp = { email: [], phone: [] };
```

Then you can update those arrays; no need to construct a new array on every key:

```
otp[$(this).data('channel')][$(this).data("index")] = $(this).val();
```

Note also that `data-` attributes can be accessed more easily via the jQuery `.data()` method.

If your "channel" names are not predictable, all you need to do is initialize the arrays when you see a new one:

```
if (!otp[$(this).data('channel')])
  otp[$(this).data('channel')] = [];
```

Comment: That could be done if you know the channel's name. E.g channels here are email, phone etc. But channels are variable and only be calculated from data-channel. So how can I define an object of dynamic objects of array?

Comment: @SkyRar your question did not mention that detail, but I'll extend the answer.

Comment: `otp[$(this).data('channel')][$(this).data("index")] = $(this).val();` This helps only if you know the channels name e.g email, phone . But in my case I dont know the channel's name.