# How to invoke the map functional from a javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is the `map()` not being invoked here?

```js
let N = 16;
let fullSizeBufs = Array(2).map((x) =>
  Array(N).fill(-1)
)
console.log(fullSizeBufs)
```

We get

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

I even put a breakpoint on the  `Array(N).fill(-1)` : it is not hit. The `map()` is just skipped.  What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Thanks @Phil for putting in the `code snippet`: I'll try to pick up that little skill!

Comment: You might be interested in `Array.from({ length: N }, () => -1)` as well

Comment: @Phil yes - that's more directly expressing the intent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)  and   [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array)  Seriously everything on SO is so hard to find nowadays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a spread operator with the first array to make it iterable.

```js
let N = 16;
let fullSizeBufs = [...Array(2)].map((x) =>
  Array(N).fill(-1)
)
console.log(fullSizeBufs)
```

Comment: I like this better than `Array(2).fill(0)`

Comment: ES6 is the gift that keeps on giving.

Answer (score 3):

You have to fill the first array, or map has nothing to iterate on.  The Array constructor initializes with references undefined, which is not the same as [undefined, undefined, undefined], which is actually an array of 3 references to undefined.
eg: `[,,,].map(x=>console.log(x))` vs `[undefined,undefined,undefined].map(x=>console.log(x))`

```js
let N = 16;
let fullSizeBufs = Array(2).fill(0).map((x) =>
  Array(N).fill(-1)
)
console.log(fullSizeBufs)
```

Comment: ah ya - I'm still a bit color blind wrt javascript

Comment: This is probably the most direct answer but I like the `spread operator` approach as well