# The mysterious flatMap: cannot flatMap the inner array which is created with new Array(1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I checked the MDN for both flatMap/map but still cannot understand why the third test fails:

```
  describe("mysterious flatMap", () => {
    it("an array will be mapped to an array of `undefined` when its element NOT set", () => {
      const mapped = new Array(1).map(() => "x");
      expect(mapped.length).toBe(1); //OK
      expect(mapped[0]).toBe(undefined); // OK
    });
    it("flatMap can join array of `undefined`", () => {
      const flat = [undefined].flatMap((_) => [undefined]);
      expect(flat.length).toBe(1); // OK
      expect(flat[0]).toBe(undefined); //OK
    });
    it("but flatMap can NOT join the array which is created without elements set, why ??", () => {
      const flat = [undefined].flatMap((_) => new Array(1).map(() => "x"));
      expect(flat.length).toBe(1); // Error, Received: 0
      expect(flat[0]).toBe("x");
    });
  });
```

I also created [an online test on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-elbakyan-rvtke?file=/src/array-flatmap.spec.ts)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Flatmapping an array with one element into an empty array leads to...an empty array. Not sure why you expected otherwise.

Comment: `flat` and `flatMap` remove holes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#flattening_and_array_holes

Comment: "*"an array will be mapped to an array of `undefined` when its element NOT set"*" that's not really what happens. You have an array of empty slots. It's not an array of `undefined`.

Comment: Incidentally, that's also what a sparse array is - full of holes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#flattening_and_array_holes)

> `flatMap` is identical to a `map()` followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately

And

> The flat method removes empty slots (holes) in arrays

---

This code

```
new Array(1).map(() => "x")
```

does NOT return `[undefined]`. It creates a sparse array (an array of holes)

([JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581))

So, your last block of code is equivalent to `[empty x 1].flat(1)` which results in an empty array.

Comment: Even more precisely, `new Array(1).map(() => "x")` is equivalent to just having `new Array(1)` because `.map` will skip all empty slots. Which is all of them.