# Why array with spread and map generate an array with undefined values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone explain me why this statement generates a new array of null values instead a array of 1's?

```js
let a = [...Array(3).map(_ => 1)];
console.log(a);
```

results `[null, null, null]` instead of `[1,1,1]`

But, the following code...

```js
let b = [...Array(3)].map(_ => 1)
console.log(b);
```

results `[1,1,1]`

Comment: Both seem to return `[1,1,1]`.

Comment: I edited the question to say what I think you mean.

Comment: ... and I had to google to figure out why.  I think it's a dup of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501711/294949

Answer (score 2):

Some might consider this a dup of the post I referred to in the comments.  The gist is that the array constructor creates an *array of undefined references*, and the spread operator creates an array of *references to undefined*.

`map` skips undefined references, but maps happily over refs to undefined. See it with a  `console.log()` side effect.

```js
new Array(3).map(el => console.log('this code is never reached'))
```

Compared this to

```js
[...new Array(3)].map(el => console.log(el))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you creating empty array that have a length, all slots are unassigned, they don't even have `undefined` value. Map on
the other hand, can only iterate thru assigned values.

Good explanation is on developer.mozilla.org

[MDN Array()->Parameters->arrayLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#parameters)

> (...) Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values (...)

[MDN map()->description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#description)

> (...) callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values (...)

This is why on `Array(3).map(_=>1)`, `map()` callback have no effect.

Second part is how spread is working. When you are spreading array with 3 empty slots, you are creating new array, that have
filled slots. Now you have all slots with value undefined. From now, map will work as expected.

Examples:

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.20.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> Array(3)
[ <3 empty items> ]

> [...Array(3)]
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]

> const a = []
> a.length = 2
> a
[ <2 empty items> ]

> [...a]
[ undefined, undefined ]
```