# Difference between not initialized and undefined value

Tags: javascript, variables, types, undefined

```
let a = Array(3);
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = undefined;

function test(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => !!a);
}

console.log('before', a); // [1, undefined, undefined]
console.log('after', test(a)); // [true, false, undefined]
```

How can I check if array element is initialized as undefined (a[1]) or not initialized (a[2])? a[2] has empty value, but browser converts it to undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Comment: @derpirscher: That does not explain how to determine whether a value has been set or not, at any index.

Comment: Well, your "bug" turned out to be one way to test :D. Not going to say if this is the best method or not, though, so keep looking for answers!

Comment: what is actually the wanted result? `map` returns `undefined` for sparse items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` with the index.
When no value at the index is set, `hasOwnProperty` returns `false`:

```js
const a = Array(3);
a[1] = undefined;

console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(0));
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(1));
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(2));
```

`in` works as well:

```js
const a = Array(3);
a[1] = undefined;

console.log(0 in a);
console.log(1 in a);
console.log(2 in a);
```

Comment: It's works, I can filter empty values and keep undefined by `arr.filter((a, i, arr) => arr.hasOwnProperty(i));` thanks

Comment: or just `in` ...